# How to remove all non printable characters in a string?

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii

I imagine I need to remove chars 0-31 and 127.

Is there a function or piece of code to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 464, accepted):

### 7 bit ASCII?

If your Tardis just landed in 1963, and you just want the 7 bit printable ASCII chars, you can rip out everything from 0-31 and 127-255 with this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

It matches anything in range 0-31, 127-255 and removes it.

### 8 bit extended ASCII?

You fell into a Hot Tub Time Machine, and you're back in the eighties. 
If you've got some form of 8 bit ASCII, then you might want to keep the chars in range 128-255. An easy adjustment - just look for 0-31 and 127

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $string);
```

### UTF-8?

Ah, welcome back to the 21st century. If you have a UTF-8 encoded string, then the `/u` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) can be used on the regex

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string);
```

This just removes 0-31 and 127. This works in ASCII and UTF-8 because both share the [same control set range](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) (as noted by mgutt below). Strictly speaking, this would work without the `/u` modifier. But it makes life easier if you want to remove other chars...

If you're dealing with Unicode, there are [potentially many non-printing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770117/what-is-the-range-of-unicode-printable-characters), but let's consider a simple one: [NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0)](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/)

In a UTF-8 string, this would be encoded as `0xC2A0`. You could look for and remove that specific sequence, but with the `/u` modifier in place, you can simply add `\xA0` to the character class:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', $string);
```

### Addendum: What about str_replace?

preg_replace is pretty efficient, but if you're doing this operation a lot, you could build an array of chars you want to remove, and use str_replace as noted by mgutt below, e.g.

```
//build an array we can re-use across several operations
$badchar=array(
    // control characters
    chr(0), chr(1), chr(2), chr(3), chr(4), chr(5), chr(6), chr(7), chr(8), chr(9), chr(10),
    chr(11), chr(12), chr(13), chr(14), chr(15), chr(16), chr(17), chr(18), chr(19), chr(20),
    chr(21), chr(22), chr(23), chr(24), chr(25), chr(26), chr(27), chr(28), chr(29), chr(30),
    chr(31),
    // non-printing characters
    chr(127)
);

//replace the unwanted chars
$str2 = str_replace($badchar, '', $str);
```

Intuitively, this seems like it would be fast, but it's not always the case, you should definitely benchmark to see if it saves you anything. I did some benchmarks across a variety string lengths with random data, and this pattern emerged using php 7.0.12

```
     2 chars str_replace     5.3439ms preg_replace     2.9919ms preg_replace is 44.01% faster
     4 chars str_replace     6.0701ms preg_replace     1.4119ms preg_replace is 76.74% faster
     8 chars str_replace     5.8119ms preg_replace     2.0721ms preg_replace is 64.35% faster
    16 chars str_replace     6.0401ms preg_replace     2.1980ms preg_replace is 63.61% faster
    32 chars str_replace     6.0320ms preg_replace     2.6770ms preg_replace is 55.62% faster
    64 chars str_replace     7.4198ms preg_replace     4.4160ms preg_replace is 40.48% faster
   128 chars str_replace    12.7239ms preg_replace     7.5412ms preg_replace is 40.73% faster
   256 chars str_replace    19.8820ms preg_replace    17.1330ms preg_replace is 13.83% faster
   512 chars str_replace    34.3399ms preg_replace    34.0221ms preg_replace is  0.93% faster
  1024 chars str_replace    57.1141ms preg_replace    67.0300ms str_replace  is 14.79% faster
  2048 chars str_replace    94.7111ms preg_replace   123.3189ms str_replace  is 23.20% faster
  4096 chars str_replace   227.7029ms preg_replace   258.3771ms str_replace  is 11.87% faster
  8192 chars str_replace   506.3410ms preg_replace   555.6269ms str_replace  is  8.87% faster
 16384 chars str_replace  1116.8811ms preg_replace  1098.0589ms preg_replace is  1.69% faster
 32768 chars str_replace  2299.3128ms preg_replace  2222.8632ms preg_replace is  3.32% faster
```

The timings themselves are for 10000 iterations, but what's more interesting is the relative differences. Up to 512 chars, I was seeing preg_replace alway win. In the 1-8kb range, str_replace had a marginal edge.

I thought it was interesting result, so including it here. *The important thing is not to take this result and use it to decide which method to use, but to benchmark against your own data and then decide.*

Comment: If you need to consider a newline safe, change the expression to this (inversely search for printables): preg_replace(/[^\x0A\x20-\x7E]/,'',$string);

Comment: @Dalin There is no such thing as an “UTF-8 character”. There are Unicode symbols/characters, and UTF-8 is an encoding that can represent all of them. You meant to say this doesn’t work for characters outside of the ASCII character set.

Comment: If you need to match a unicode character above \xFF, use \x{####}

Comment: you missed \x7F (127) which is a non-printable character

Comment: this will remove Arabic letters, bad solution.

Comment: Hi is there a way that it can preserve new lines? I'm using it and it actually deletes special characters from my string but my string is for example 20 lines. The output is now one-line (All 20 lines were combined).

Comment: &#13; is an encoding, not a character. The solution above is only intended to work on ASCII characters.

Comment: Does it preserve spaces?

Comment: A space is 32 (0x20), so yes.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is completely wrong, see mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42058165/318765

Comment: @mgutt I've clarified the answer. See also interesting benchmark result on str_replace.

Comment: Remove the deletion of 128-255. There does not exist something like a "7-bit extended ascii table". The only 128-255 control set I know is the one in UTF-8 and this should not be touched as it could contain (in Windows) the euro sign and other characters as stated in my answer. P.S I verified your benchmark. `preg_replace`is faster.

Comment: P.S. maybe you think about adding `chr(160) (NO-BREAK SPACE)` and `chr(173) (SOFT HYPHEN)`. They are non-printable, too.

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', $string);` worked perfectly to sanitize data from `iptcparse`, thank you!

Comment: Didn't work with LSEP, for example:  `print(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', "  An"));`
Dalin's answer worked with [:print:]... Stackoverflow is stripping LSEP it seems...

Comment: I need to remove every space and nbsp (160), so this `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $string);` is enough for me...

Comment: This fails on most whitespace, which renders as a space in browsers but gets stripped out entirely here.  [**Demo of Code Above Stripping Out Whitespace**](https://ideone.com/VtBHr6)

Comment: If you want to check binary data, like a file, you have to remove the "u" modifier from the UTF-8 solution. The documentation says that simply nothing will be matched, but the function seems to return a completely empty result instead. If I'm not wrong, then use the modifier for UTF encoded texts and remove it if using with other binary data, like files.

Answer (score 161):

Many of the other answers here do not take into account unicode characters (e.g. öäüßйȝîûηыეமிᚉ⠛ ).  In this case you can use the following:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/u', '', $string);
```

There's a strange class of characters in the range `\x80-\x9F` (Just above the 7-bit ASCII range of characters) that are technically control characters, but over time have been misused for printable characters. If you don't have any problems with these, then you can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string);
```

If you wish to also strip line feeds, carriage returns, tabs, non-breaking spaces, and soft-hyphens, you can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xA0\xAD]/u', '', $string);
```

Note that you *must* use single quotes for the above examples.

If you wish to strip everything except basic printable ASCII characters (all the example characters above will be stripped) you can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', $string);
```

For reference see http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm

Comment: Your regexp handles UTF8 characters fine; but it strips non-UTF8 "special" characters; like ç, ü and ö. `'/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xC0]/u'`leaves them intact; but also division (F7) and multiplication (D7) sign.

Comment: @Hazar yes you are correct \x80-\xFF stripped out too much, but \x80-\xC0 is still too restrictive.  This would miss other printable characters like ©£±.  For reference see http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: The third example with :print: behaves differently on different machines. It worked on localhost, but didn't strip the same characters on our live server. The first example stripped regular numbers from my string on localhost.

Comment: @JoshRibakoff I don't see how [:print:] could show different results on different machines, it is a POSIX standard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes also I don't see how the first example could strip regular numbers, you'll need to give more info.

Comment: Not sure what more info to give. Perhaps some server setting differed such as the locale. I don't know where to start to debug it, I fixed it using a whitelist of allowed characters which was kind of a pain but ended up getting the job done.

Comment: @Dalin I noticed at least the second option doesn't work with double quotes, but it does with single quotes. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @TimMalone because PHP will expand those character sequences: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double so the regex won't see the range that you're trying to tell it about.

Comment: What about 7F? Should it not be `\x7F-\x9F`?

Comment: @Bell Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the euro sign `\x80` and all the other printable characters?!  Look my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42058165/318765

Comment: @mgutt [`\x80` isn't the euro in unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm),  [`\x20AC` is](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm). [`\x80` is the euro in some other encodings](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/EuroSymbolFAQ.mspx) but in Unicode it's technically a control character.  If you want to leave it in, go for it.

Comment: @Dalin Read my answer. I provided sources were you can see the behaviour. It seems to be a backwards compatibility to CP-1252. Test it by yourself through entering `&#x20AC; &#x80; &#128;` on this website: https://mothereff.in/html-entities I see three euro signs.

Comment: I just tried a lot, i tried every encoding function available in PHP from regex to mb_ to htmlspecialchars etc.
Nothing removed control characters, thanks for investing the work.

Comment: :print is too restrictive and will loose euro and pound signs among other things. Just use `/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xC0]/u`

Answer (score 48):

Starting with PHP 5.2, we also have access to filter_var, which I have not seen any mention of so thought I'd throw it out there.  To use filter_var to strip non-printable characters < 32 and > 127, you can do:

Filter ASCII characters below 32

```
$string = filter_var($input, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
```

Filter ASCII characters above 127

```
$string = filter_var($input, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

Strip both:

```
$string = filter_var($input, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

You can also html-encode low characters (newline, tab, etc.) while stripping high:

```
$string = filter_var($input, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

There are also options for stripping HTML, sanitizing e-mails and URLs, etc. So, lots of options for sanitization (strip out data) and even validation (return false if not valid rather than silently stripping).

**Sanitization:** http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

**Validation:** http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

However, there is still the problem, that the FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW will strip out newline and carriage returns, which for a textarea are completely valid characters...so some of the Regex answers, I guess, are still necessary at times, e.g. after reviewing this thread, I plan to do this for textareas:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]\r\n]/', '',$input);
```

This seems more readable than a number of the regexes that stripped out by numeric range.

Comment: Other answers didn't work for me, the "filter_var()" solution did it perfectly. Thanks after 7 years! :)

Answer (score 27):

you can use character classes

```
/[[:cntrl:]]+/
```

Comment: doesn't this require me to use ereg though?

Answer (score 25):

All of the solutions work partially, and even below probably does not cover all of the cases.  My issue was in trying to insert a string into a utf8 mysql table.  The string (and its bytes) all conformed to utf8, but had several bad sequences.  I assume that most of them were control or formatting.

```
function clean_string($string) {
  $s = trim($string);
  $s = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $s); // drop all non utf-8 characters

  // this is some bad utf-8 byte sequence that makes mysql complain - control and formatting i think
  $s = preg_replace('/(?>[\x00-\x1F]|\xC2[\x80-\x9F]|\xE2[\x80-\x8F]{2}|\xE2\x80[\xA4-\xA8]|\xE2\x81[\x9F-\xAF])/', ' ', $s);

  $s = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $s); // reduce all multiple whitespace to a single space

  return $s;
}
```

To further exacerbate the problem is the table vs. server vs. connection vs. rendering of the content, as [talked about a little here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623733/utf-8-problems-php-mysql)

Comment: \xE2\x80[\xA4-\xA8] (or 226.128.[164-168]) - is wrong, the sequence include next printable symbols:
Unicode Character 'ONE DOT LEADER' (U+2024),
Unicode Character 'TWO DOT LEADER' (U+2025),
Unicode Character 'HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS' (U+2026),
Unicode Character 'HYPHENATION POINT' (U+2027).

And only one non-printable: Unicode Character 'LINE SEPARATOR' (U+2028). Next one is non-printable too: Unicode Character 'PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR' (U+2029).

So replace the sequence with: \xE2\x80[\xA8-\xA9]
\xE2\x80[\xA8-\xA9] to remove LINE SEPARATOR and PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR.

Comment: This is the best solution I could find so far, but I laso had to add `$s = preg_replace('/(\xF0\x9F[\x00-\xFF][\x00-\xFF])/', ' ', $s);` because of all the emoji characters were messing up mysql

Comment: Unfortunately the "bad utf-8" Regex above also removes line breaks!

Answer (score 18):

this is simpler:

> $string = preg_replace(
>   '/[^[:cntrl:]]/', '',$string);

Comment: This also strips line feeds, carriage returns, and UTF8 characters.

Comment: @Dalin There is no such thing as an “UTF-8 character”. There are Unicode symbols/characters, and UTF-8 is an encoding that can represent all of them. You meant to say this strips _characters outside of the ASCII range_ as well.

Comment: Eats up Arabic characters :)

Answer (score 15):

To strip all non-ASCII characters from the input string

`$result = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);`

That code removes any characters in the hex ranges 0-31 and 128-255, leaving only the hex characters 32-127 in the resulting string, which I call $result in this example.

Comment: Why would I want 127, which is DEL ? Wouldn't it be better as `[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]` to remove 127 to 255 instead of 128 to 255 ?

Answer (score 13):

For UTF-8, try this:

`preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\s]/u','', $string);`

That was my original answer form 10 years ago, and as the comments are saying this is well suited for feeding a full text search engine, as it removes some non-text printable characters like []!~ etc.

If you also need to remove invalid characters for say, feeding `libexpat` (sigh.), you can try:

`preg_replace('/[^\PCc^\PCn^\PCs]/u', '', $string);`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66587087/279538) for more on the method.

Comment: This well remove characters like quotes, brackets, etc. Those are certainly printable characters.

Comment: this is wonderful!  it saved my life, messed up while printing Arabic characters, worked like champ :)

Comment: This can be useful when only pure words are needed. For example, for a search engine on the page and an index in the database. Parentheses, periods and commas are then unnecessary.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a regular express to remove everything apart from those characters you wish to keep:

```
$string=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 _\-\+\&]/','',$string);
```

Replaces everything that is not (^) the letters A-Z or a-z, the numbers 0-9, space, underscore, hypen, plus and ampersand - with nothing (i.e. remove it).

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_replace('/(?!\n)[\p{Cc}]/', '', $response);
```

This will remove all the control characters (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) leaving the `\n` newline characters. From my experience, the control characters are the ones that most often cause the printing issues.

Comment: It works perfect for me! I added just `/u` for UTF-8 chars. Could you please explain what the first part `(?!\n)` does?

Comment: Perfect ! I was looking for a way to remove unicode 'useless' characters and keep the important one (letters including accent, numbers, special chars) . Thanks for the answer and the documentation link

Answer (score 5):

The [answer of @PaulDixon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176923/318765) <strike>is **completely wrong**, because it **removes the printable** [extended ASCII characters](http://www.ascii-code.com/) 128-255!</strike> has been partially corrected. I don't know why he still wants to delete 128-255 from a 127 chars 7-bit ASCII set as it does not have the extended ASCII characters.

But finally it was important not to delete 128-255 because for example `chr(128)` (`\x80`) is the euro sign in 8-bit ASCII and many UTF-8 fonts in Windows [display a euro sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4640368/318765) and Android regarding my own test.

And it will kill many UTF-8 characters if you remove the ASCII chars 128-255 from an UTF-8 string (probably the starting bytes of a multi-byte UTF-8 character). So don't do that! They are completely legal characters in all currently used file systems. [The only reserved range is 0-31](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42058764/318765).

Instead use this to delete the non-printable characters 0-31 and 127:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $string);
```

It **works in ASCII and UTF-8** because both share the [same control set range](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm).

The <strike>fastest</strike> slower¹ alternative without using regular expressions:

```
$string = str_replace(array(
    // control characters
    chr(0), chr(1), chr(2), chr(3), chr(4), chr(5), chr(6), chr(7), chr(8), chr(9), chr(10),
    chr(11), chr(12), chr(13), chr(14), chr(15), chr(16), chr(17), chr(18), chr(19), chr(20),
    chr(21), chr(22), chr(23), chr(24), chr(25), chr(26), chr(27), chr(28), chr(29), chr(30),
    chr(31),
    // non-printing characters
    chr(127)
), '', $string);
```

If you want to keep all whitespace characters `\t`, `\n` and `\r`, then remove `chr(9)`, `chr(10)` and `chr(13)` from this list. Note: The usual whitespace is `chr(32)` so it stays in the result. Decide yourself if you want to remove non-breaking space `chr(160)` as it can cause problems.

¹ Tested by @PaulDixon and verified by myself.

Answer (score 3):

The regex into selected answer fail for Unicode: 0x1d (with php 7.4)

a solution:

```
<?php
        $ct = 'différents'."\r\n test";

        // fail for Unicode: 0x1d
        $ct = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]$/u', '',$ct);

        // work for Unicode: 0x1d
        $ct =  preg_replace( '/[^\P{C}]+/u', "",  $ct);

        // work for Unicode: 0x1d and allow line break
        $ct =  preg_replace( '/[^\P{C}\n]+/u', "",  $ct);

        echo $ct;
```

from:
[UTF 8 String remove all invisible characters except newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543476/utf-8-string-remove-all-invisible-characters-except-newline)

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9`_.,;@#%~'\"\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:\-\s\\\\]+/", "", $data);
```

gives me complete control of what I want to include

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is still looking how to do this without removing the non-printable characters, but rather escaping them, I made this to help out. Feel free to improve it! Characters are escaped to \\x[A-F0-9][A-F0-9].

Call like so:

```
$escaped = EscapeNonASCII($string);

$unescaped = UnescapeNonASCII($string);
```

---

```
<?php 
  function EscapeNonASCII($string) //Convert string to hex, replace non-printable chars with escaped hex
    {
        $hexbytes = strtoupper(bin2hex($string));
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < strlen($hexbytes))
        {
            $hexpair = substr($hexbytes, $i, 2);
            $decimal = hexdec($hexpair);
            if ($decimal < 32 || $decimal > 126)
            {
                $top = substr($hexbytes, 0, $i);
                $escaped = EscapeHex($hexpair);
                $bottom = substr($hexbytes, $i + 2);
                $hexbytes = $top . $escaped . $bottom;
                $i += 8;
            }
            $i += 2;
        }
        $string = hex2bin($hexbytes);
        return $string;
    }
    function EscapeHex($string) //Helper function for EscapeNonASCII()
    {
        $x = "5C5C78"; //\x
        $topnibble = bin2hex($string[0]); //Convert top nibble to hex
        $bottomnibble = bin2hex($string[1]); //Convert bottom nibble to hex
        $escaped = $x . $topnibble . $bottomnibble; //Concatenate escape sequence "\x" with top and bottom nibble
        return $escaped;
    }

    function UnescapeNonASCII($string) //Convert string to hex, replace escaped hex with actual hex.
    {
        $stringtohex = bin2hex($string);
        $stringtohex = preg_replace_callback('/5c5c78([a-fA-F0-9]{4})/', function ($m) { 
            return hex2bin($m[1]);
        }, $stringtohex);
        return hex2bin(strtoupper($stringtohex));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Marked anwser is perfect but it misses character 127(DEL) which is also a non-printable character

my answer would be

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7f-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, too. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42058165/318765

Comment: above answer was a compliment to original answer which only adds up "delete" character.

Answer (score 0):

"cedivad" solved the issue for me with persistent result of Swedish chars ÅÄÖ.

```
$text = preg_replace( '/[^\p{L}\s]/u', '', $text );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one has been mentioned this:

1. as PHP functions just suppose every byte is one character.
   we have to use the `mb_` counterpart.

and if you have users from all over the world, you have to consider this, because it just drops the CJK, Arabic, Georgian characters if you stick to the PHP's `preg_replace`

2. another issue I have faced with the `mb_` was it does required pattern to be just a string & **not wrapped in the start/stop modifier** like`/pattern/im`  .
3. another note: if you use `^[:print:]` it will just preserve everything in between `0x20-0x7e` so dropping all the characters above `0x800`but if you use `[:cntrl:]` it will just dropping `0x00 - 0x1f` & `0x7f` (The 'DEL' character) . so you can easily preserve all the extended ASCII chars with this.

my working piece of code is like this:

```
$pattern = "[[:cntrl:]".PHP_EOL."]";
mb_ereg_replace($pattern, '', $text);
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved problem for UTF8 using https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

```
use ForceUTF8\Encoding;

$string = Encoding::fixUTF8($string);
```

Comment: This lib converts UTF-8 accented characters and UTF-8 emoticons to "?" symbols.
Fairly serious issue unfortunately.