# Remove non-utf8 characters from string

Tags: php, regex

Im having a problem with removing non-utf8 characters from string, which are not displaying properly. Characters are like this 0x97 0x61 0x6C 0x6F (hex representation)

What is the best way to remove them? Regular expression or something else ?

Comment: The solutions listed here didn't work for me so I found my answer here in the section "Character validation": http://webcollab.sourceforge.net/unicode.html

Comment: [Related to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string/20766625#20766625), but not necessarily a duplicate, more like a close cousin :)

Comment: `$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');` from https://stackoverflow.com/q/8215050/1066234 (leaves "?" symbol for non-UTF8 characters).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using a regex approach:

```
$regex = <<<'END'
/
  (
    (?: [\x00-\x7F]                 # single-byte sequences   0xxxxxxx
    |   [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]      # double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
    |   [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}   # triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
    |   [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}   # quadruple-byte sequence 11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3 
    ){1,100}                        # ...one or more times
  )
| .                                 # anything else
/x
END;
preg_replace($regex, '$1', $text);
```

It searches for UTF-8 sequences, and captures those into group 1. It also matches single bytes that could not be identified as part of a UTF-8 sequence, but does not capture those. Replacement is whatever was captured into group 1. This effectively removes all invalid bytes.

It is possible to repair the string, by encoding the invalid bytes as UTF-8 characters. But if the errors are random, this could leave some strange symbols.

```
$regex = <<<'END'
/
  (
    (?: [\x00-\x7F]               # single-byte sequences   0xxxxxxx
    |   [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]    # double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
    |   [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} # triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
    |   [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3} # quadruple-byte sequence 11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3 
    ){1,100}                      # ...one or more times
  )
| ( [\x80-\xBF] )                 # invalid byte in range 10000000 - 10111111
| ( [\xC0-\xFF] )                 # invalid byte in range 11000000 - 11111111
/x
END;
function utf8replacer($captures) {
  if ($captures[1] != "") {
    // Valid byte sequence. Return unmodified.
    return $captures[1];
  }
  elseif ($captures[2] != "") {
    // Invalid byte of the form 10xxxxxx.
    // Encode as 11000010 10xxxxxx.
    return "\xC2".$captures[2];
  }
  else {
    // Invalid byte of the form 11xxxxxx.
    // Encode as 11000011 10xxxxxx.
    return "\xC3".chr(ord($captures[3])-64);
  }
}
preg_replace_callback($regex, "utf8replacer", $text);
```

**EDIT:**

- `!empty(x)` will match non-empty values (`"0"` is considered empty).
- `x != ""` will match non-empty values, including `"0"`.
- `x !== ""` will match anything except `""`.

`x != ""` seem the best one to use in this case.

I have also sped up the match a little. Instead of matching each character separately, it matches sequences of valid UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 150):

If you apply `utf8_encode()` to an already UTF8 string it will return a garbled UTF8 output.

I made a function that addresses all this issues.  It´s called `Encoding::toUTF8()`.

You dont need to know what the encoding of your strings is.  It can be Latin1 (ISO8859-1), Windows-1252 or UTF8, or the string can have a mix of them. `Encoding::toUTF8()` will convert everything to UTF8.

I did it because a service was giving me a feed of data all messed up, mixing those encodings in the same string.

Usage:

```
require_once('Encoding.php'); 
use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;  // It's namespaced now.

$utf8_string = Encoding::toUTF8($mixed_string);

$latin1_string = Encoding::toLatin1($mixed_string);
```

I've included another function, Encoding::fixUTF8(), which will fix every UTF8 string that looks garbled product of having been encoded into UTF8 multiple times.

Usage:

```
require_once('Encoding.php'); 
use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;  // It's namespaced now.

$utf8_string = Encoding::fixUTF8($garbled_utf8_string);
```

Examples:

```
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂ©dÃÂ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂÃÂ©dÃÂÃÂ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂ©dération Camerounaise de Football");
```

will output:

```
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
```

Download:

https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

Comment: Outstanding stuff! All the other solutions discard invalid chars, but this one fixes it. Awesome.

Comment: The second part of Markus Jarderot's answer also does that.

Comment: Brilliant but how to discard invalid chars? is there a function to do that?

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez-Ocampo, Then this is not the function you need. Use this only when you want to apply a "fix" to it.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli, Have there been test cases verifying the security of this function?

Comment: @Pacerier, please contact me on github to discuss potential vulnerabilities so I can add those tests.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli I have been trying to use fixUTF8() function but it results to ? but I need to replace it with nothing ''. How can I do that?

Comment: When trying to remove accented "i" this does not work with the following string: `231 Vía La Paz` --  Returns with the same `í`

Answer (score 93):

You can use mbstring:

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

...will remove invalid characters.

See: [Replacing invalid UTF-8 characters by question marks, mbstring.substitute_character seems ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215050/replacing-invalid-utf-8-characters-by-question-marks-mbstring-substitute-charac)

Comment: @Alliswell which ones? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: sure, ```<0x1a>```

Comment: @Alliswell If I'm not mistaken `<0x1a>`, although not printable character, is a perfectly valid UTF-8 sequence. You might have issues with non-printable characters? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string

Comment: Before calling mb convert, I had to set the mbstring substitute character to none `ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', 'none');` otherwise I was getting question marks in the result.

Comment: @MaximePacary `"\xFF"` then, that's invalid UTF-8

Comment: @hanshenrik Then the corresponding invalid UTF-8 sequence should be removed by `mb_convert_encoding()`, as the OP asked (I'm not 100% sure to understand your point?)

Answer (score 30):

**This function removes all NON ASCII characters, it's useful but not solving the question:**
This is my function that always works, regardless of encoding:

```
function remove_bs($Str) {  
  $StrArr = str_split($Str); $NewStr = '';
  foreach ($StrArr as $Char) {    
    $CharNo = ord($Char);
    if ($CharNo == 163) { $NewStr .= $Char; continue; } // keep £ 
    if ($CharNo > 31 && $CharNo < 127) {
      $NewStr .= $Char;    
    }
  }  
  return $NewStr;
}
```

How it works:

```
echo remove_bs('Hello õhowå åare youÆ?'); // Hello how are you?
```

Comment: it is ASCII and not even close to what the question wanted.

Comment: This one worked. I faced the problem when Google Maps API reported the error due to 'non-UTF-8 character' in the API request URL. The culprit was `í` character in the address field which IS a valid UTF-8 character [see table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). The morale: do not trust API error messages :)

Comment: I like this one, but use `mb_str_split()` and `mb_ord()` to get the correct CharNo.

Answer (score 22):

```
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);
```

This is what I am using. Seems to work pretty well. Taken from http://planetozh.com/blog/2005/01/remove-invalid-characters-in-utf-8/

Comment: didn't work for me. I wish I could attach the tested line, but unfortunately it has invalid chars.

Comment: Sorry, after some more testing I realized this wasn't really doing what I thought. I'm now using http://stackoverflow.com/a/8215387/138023

Answer (score 18):

try this:

```
$string = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$string);
```

According to the [iconv manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), the function will take the first parameter as the input charset, second parameter as the output charset, and the third as the actual input string.

If you set both the input and output charset to **UTF-8**, and append the `//IGNORE` flag to the output charset, the function will drop(strip) all characters in the input string that can't be represented by the output charset. Thus, filtering the input string in effect.

Comment: I've tried this, and the `//IGNORE` doesn't seem to suppress the notice that invalid UTF-8 is present (which, of course, I know about, and want to fix). A highly rated comment [in the manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) seems to think it has been a bug for some years.

Comment: Is always better to use `iconv`. @halfer Maybe your input data is not from utf-8. Another option is to make a re-conversion to ascii then back to utf-8 again. In my case i did used `iconv` like `$output = iconv("UTF-8//", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $input );`

Comment: @erm3nda: I exactly don't remember my use case for this - might have have parsing a UTF-8 website declared with the wrong charset. Thanks for the note, I am sure that will be useful for a future reader.

Comment: Yes, if you don't know something, just test for it and finally you'll hit the key ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Hi There you can use simple regex

```
$text = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $text);
```

It would truncate all non UTF-8 characters from string

Comment: This also deletes valid japanese characters.

Answer (score 10):

The text may contain **non-utf8 character**. Try to do first:

```
$nonutf8 = mb_convert_encoding($nonutf8 , 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php[news][2]

Answer (score 9):

UConverter can be used since PHP 5.5. UConverter is better the choice if you use intl extension and don't use mbstring.

```
function replace_invalid_byte_sequence($str)
{
    return UConverter::transcode($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
}

function replace_invalid_byte_sequence2($str)
{
    return (new UConverter('UTF-8', 'UTF-8'))->convert($str);
}
```

htmlspecialchars can be used to remove invalid byte sequence since PHP 5.4. Htmlspecialchars is better than preg_match for handling large size of byte and the accuracy. A lot of the wrong implementation by using regular expression can be seen.

```
function replace_invalid_byte_sequence3($str)
{
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8'));
}
```

Comment: You have three nice solutions, but it's not clear how a user would choose among them.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to 2019 and the `/u` modifier in regex which will handle UTF-8 multibyte chars for you

If you only use `mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')` you will still end up with non-printable chars in your string

This method will:

- Remove all invalid UTF-8 multibyte chars with `mb_convert_encoding`
- Remove all non-printable chars like `\r`, `\x00` (NULL-byte) and other control chars with `preg_replace`

## method:

```
function utf8_filter(string $value): string{
    return preg_replace('/[^[:print:]\n]/u', '', mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'));
}
```

`[:print:]` match all printable chars and `\n` newlines and strip everything else

You can see the ASCII table below.. The printable chars range from 32 to 127, but newline `\n` is a part of the control chars which range from 0 to 31 so we have to add newline to the regex `/[^[:print:]\n]/u`

[image: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1014/5789/files/Standard-ASCII-Table_large.jpg?10669400161723642407]

You can try to send strings through the regex with chars outside the printable range like `\x7F` (DEL), `\x1B` (Esc) etc. and see how they are stripped

```
function utf8_filter(string $value): string{
    return preg_replace('/[^[:print:]\n]/u', '', mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'));
}

$arr = [
    'Danish chars'          => 'Hello from Denmark with æøå',
    'Non-printable chars'   => "\x7FHello with invalid chars\r \x00"
];

foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    echo "$k:\n---------\n";
    
    $len = strlen($v);
    echo "$v\n(".$len.")\n";
    
    $strip = utf8_decode(utf8_filter(utf8_encode($v)));
    $strip_len = strlen($strip);
    echo $strip."\n(".$strip_len.")\n\n";
    
    echo "Chars removed: ".($len - $strip_len)."\n\n\n";
}
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/q5sJ3FOddhv1atpR

Comment: Welcome in 2047, where `php-mbstring` is not packed in php by default.

Comment: What if your environment uses `\r` wth `\n`? Why not `\R`?

Comment: Running `utf8_encode` before calling this function makes no sense. If your string is in ISO 8859-1 encoding, that function will make it into UTF-8; if it's anything else - including UTF-8 - it will make it into a garbled string, which will be valid UTF-8. So you end up running the "remove non-printables" regex on the garbled string, and getting a bunch of nonsense out the other end.

Comment: This still replaces ó or similar with ?

Answer (score 7):

I have made a function that deletes invalid UTF-8 characters from a string. 
I'm using it to clear description of 27000 products before it generates the XML export file.

```
public function stripInvalidXml($value) {
    $ret = "";
    $current;
    if (empty($value)) {
        return $ret;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $current = ord($value{$i});
        if (($current == 0x9) || ($current == 0xA) || ($current == 0xD) || (($current >= 0x20) && ($current <= 0xD7FF)) || (($current >= 0xE000) && ($current <= 0xFFFD)) || (($current >= 0x10000) && ($current <= 0x10FFFF))) {
                $ret .= chr($current);
        }
        else {
            $ret .= "";
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: I am confused by this function. `ord()` returns results in the range 0-255. The giant `if` in this function tests for unicode ranges that `ord()` will never return. If anybody wants to clarify why this function works the way it does I'd appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 5):

```
$string = preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

Answer (score 5):

**substr() can break your multi-byte characters!**

In my case, I was using `substr($string, 0, 255)` to ensure a user supplied value would fit in the database.  On occasion it would split a multi-byte character in half and caused database errors with "Incorrect string value".

You could use `mb_substr($string,0,255)`, and it might be ok for MySQL 5, but MySQL 4 counts bytes instead of characters, so it would still be too long depending on the number of multi-byte characters.

To prevent these issues I implemented the following steps:

1. I increased the size of the field (in this case it was a log of changes, so preventing the longer input was not an option.)
2. I still did a `mb_substring` in case it was still too long
3. I used the accepted answer above by @Markus Jarderot to ensure if there is a really long entry with a multi-byte character right at the length limit, that we can strip out the half of a multi-byte character at the end.

Comment: Very underrated. substr broke it :)

Answer (score 4):

So the rules are that the first [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) octlet has the high bit set as a marker, and then 1 to 4 bits to indicate how many additional octlets; then each of the additional octlets must have the high two bits set to 10.

The pseudo-python would be:

```
newstring = ''
cont = 0
for each ch in string:
  if cont:
    if (ch >> 6) != 2: # high 2 bits are 10
      # do whatever, e.g. skip it, or skip whole point, or?
    else:
      # acceptable continuation of multi-octlet char
      newstring += ch
    cont -= 1
  else:
    if (ch >> 7): # high bit set?
      c = (ch << 1) # strip the high bit marker
      while (c & 1): # while the high bit indicates another octlet
        c <<= 1
        cont += 1
        if cont > 4:
           # more than 4 octels not allowed; cope with error
      if !cont:
        # illegal, do something sensible
      newstring += ch # or whatever
if cont:
  # last utf-8 was not terminated, cope
```

This same logic should be translatable to php.  However, its not clear what kind of stripping is to be done once you get a malformed character.

Comment: `c = (ch << 1)` will make `(c & 1)` zero the first time, skipping the loop. The test should probably be `(c & 128)`

Answer (score 4):

From recent patch to Drupal's Feeds JSON parser module:

```
//remove everything except valid letters (from any language)
$raw = preg_replace('/(?:\\\\u[\pL\p{Zs}])+/', '', $raw);
```

If you're concerned yes it retains spaces as valid characters.

Did what I needed. It removes widespread nowadays emoji-characters that don't fit into MySQL's 'utf8' character set and that gave me errors like "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value".

For details see https://www.drupal.org/node/1824506#comment-6881382

Comment: The `iconv` is far better than the old fashioned regexp based `preg_replace`, wich is deprecated nowadays.

Comment: [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is not deprecated

Comment: You are totally right, is the `ereg_replace()`, sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this snippet.  Why are you matching unicode space characters in your character class following your literal `\u`? I don't work s lot with emojis, so maybe you know more than me.  Please set up a working demo to prove how and what your preg call does.

Comment: Not working. Query parameter include %C4 what is bad utf8 and not removed from your regex.

Answer (score 1):

The next sanitizing works for me:

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$string = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all Unicode characters outside of the Unicode basic language plane:

```
$str = preg_replace("/[^\\x00-\\xFFFF]/", "", $str);
```

Comment: Your solution **works**, although invalid chars **is not** outeside of above range!

Comment: Not working, if $str come from query parameter with include %C4

Comment: Not working, string is still marked as "b" in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different to the question, but what I am doing is to use HtmlEncode(string),

pseudo code here

```
var encoded = HtmlEncode(string);
encoded = Regex.Replace(encoded, "&#\d+?;", "");
var result = HtmlDecode(encoded);
```

input and output

```
"Headlight\x007E Bracket, &#123; Cafe Racer<> Style,Â Stainless Steel 中文呢？"
"Headlight~ Bracket, &#123; Cafe Racer<> Style, Stainless Steel 中文呢？"
```

I know it's not perfect, but does the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
static $preg = <<<'END'
%(
[\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]
| [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]
| \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]
| [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}
| \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]
| \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}
| [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}
| \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}
)%xs
END;
if (preg_match_all($preg, $string, $match)) {
    $string = implode('', $match[0]);
} else {
    $string = '';
}
```

it work on our service

Comment: Can you add some context to explain how this will answer the question, instead of code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the solutions presented on this topic, but non of them worked for me, in my specific case. But I found a good solution on this link:
https://www.ryadel.com/en/php-skip-invalid-characters-utf-8-xml-file-string/

Basically, this is the function that solved for me:

```
function sanitizeXML($string)
{
    if (!empty($string)) 
    {
        // remove EOT+NOREP+EOX|EOT+<char> sequence (FatturaPA)
        $string = preg_replace('/(\x{0004}(?:\x{201A}|\x{FFFD})(?:\x{0003}|\x{0004}).)/u', '', $string);
 
        $regex = '/(
            [\xC0-\xC1] # Invalid UTF-8 Bytes
            | [\xF5-\xFF] # Invalid UTF-8 Bytes
            | \xE0[\x80-\x9F] # Overlong encoding of prior code point
            | \xF0[\x80-\x8F] # Overlong encoding of prior code point
            | [\xC2-\xDF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
            | [\xE0-\xEF](?![\x80-\xBF]{2}) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
            | [\xF0-\xF4](?![\x80-\xBF]{3}) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
            | (?<=[\x0-\x7F\xF5-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF] # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Middle
            | (?<![\xC2-\xDF]|[\xE0-\xEF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xF0-\xF4]|[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]|[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]{2})[\x80-\xBF] # Overlong Sequence
            | (?<=[\xE0-\xEF])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Short 3 byte sequence
            | (?<=[\xF0-\xF4])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]{2}) # Short 4 byte sequence
            | (?<=[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Short 4 byte sequence (2)
        )/x';
        $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
 
        $result = "";
        $current;
        $length = strlen($string);
        for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            $current = ord($string{$i});
            if (($current == 0x9) ||
                ($current == 0xA) ||
                ($current == 0xD) ||
                (($current >= 0x20) && ($current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
                (($current >= 0xE000) && ($current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
                (($current >= 0x10000) && ($current <= 0x10FFFF)))
            {
                $result .= chr($current);
            }
            else
            {
                $ret;    // use this to strip invalid character(s)
                // $ret .= " ";    // use this to replace them with spaces
            }
        }
        $string = $result;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Hope it will help some of you.

Answer (score 0):

None of the UTF functions or replacement methods above worked for me.
The only thing that worked was to just explicitly allow the characters I did want to allow. This might have been because the issue was not specifically a UTF-8 issue even though that is what json_last_error_msg() told me.

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.\-\,\/\ ]/m', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing non-utf8 characters from string:

**Using ICONV:**

```
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);
```

**Using MBSTRING:**

```
mb_substitute_character("none");
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

**Using PCRE:**

```
$text = preg_replace("/([\x{00}-\x{7E}]|[\x{C2}-\x{DF}][\x{80}-\x{BF}]|\x{E0}[\x{A0}-\x{BF}][\x{80}-\x{BF}]|[\x{E1}-\x{EC}\x{EE}\{xEF}][\x{80}-\x{BF}]{2}|\x{ED}[\x{80}-\x{9F}][\x{80}-\x{BF}]|\x{F0}[\x{90}-\x{BF}][\x{80}-\x{BF}]{2}|[\x{F1}-\x{F3}][\x{80}-\x{BF}]{3}|\x{F4}[\x{80}-\x{8F}][\x{80}-\x{BF}]{2})|(.)/s", "$1", $text);
```

Please note: 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0D etc... are valid UTF-8 code-points. If you need to remove non-printable characters - this is another question.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the most precise solution, but it gets the job done with a single line of code:

```
echo str_replace("?","",(utf8_decode($str)));
```

`utf8_decode` will convert the characters to a question mark;
`str_replace` will strip out the question marks.

Comment: What about if `$str = 'Hello?'`?

Comment: This will _also_ strip out 99% of all valid Unicode characters, i.e. the ones which cannot be represented in ISO 8859-1, because that's what utf8_decode converts to.

Answer (score -3):

How about iconv:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Haven't used it inside PHP itself but its always performed well for me on the command line. You can get it to substitute invalid characters.