# json_encode is returning NULL?

Tags: php, null, json

For some reason the item "description" returns `NULL` with the following code:

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `staff` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2') or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Here is the schema for my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `icon` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `date` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `company` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `companyurl` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `appurl` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Here is what is echoed out on the page:

```
[{"id":"4","name":"Noter 2","description":null,"icon":"http:\/\/images.apple.com\/webapps\/productivity\/images\/noter2_20091223182720-thumb.jpg","date":"1262032317","company":"dBelement, LLC","companyurl":"http:\/\/dbelement.com\/","appurl":"http:\/\/noter2.dbelement.com"},{"id":"3","name":"Noter 2","description":null,"icon":"http:\/\/images.apple.com\/webapps\/productivity\/images\/noter2_20091223182720-thumb.jpg","date":"1262032317","company":"dBelement, LLC","companyurl":"http:\/\/dbelement.com\/","appurl":"http:\/\/noter2.dbelement.com"}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Let's put the array keys in quotes, first of all.

Comment: Could you provide information on the schema of your "staff" table. Is there a column called description?

Comment: all of these fields will echo out if i just simply do an echo of `$r['description']` outside of the for() statement?

Comment: Or perhaps some example content from $r['description'] would help. What datatype is it?

Comment: could you make a screenshot  of the database shema?  ;-)

Comment: did you tryed an $r = mysql_fetch_array($result); print_r($r);

Comment: @tarnfeld but i didnt see any screenshot of the database shema, there is just text :-) no joking beside did you tryed the above 
$r = mysql_fetch_array($result); print_r($r);
and post the result as a 3 mb printscreen,

Comment: Added some more code ^^ here is screenshot: http://tarnfeldweb.com/stackoverflow.png

Comment: Use [`JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR` option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters) to see the problem (eg. the field with UTF8 will be null).

Comment: I had the same issue. It turns out that the data saved in the database has been badly encoded. French character like é,ë,' etc were translated in strange character such Ã, Ã, ¢, â‚ €. To solve the problem, make sure you clean up these strange characters. It worked for me!

Answer (score 260, accepted):

I bet you are retrieving data in non-utf8 encoding: try to put `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')` before your `SELECT` query.

Comment: hi, this answer saved my life, thank you. I was having the same problem here. I had values with non-utf8 chars like "Validação de Formulários". I know this question is a little bit old now, but that's the awesomeness of internet!!

Comment: mysql_set_charset is better for the security reason since PHP 5.2.3. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php for the details.

Comment: It is what scares me in programming! I have a schema in CHARSET Latin1 and COLLATION latin1_swedish_ci ...   Then Why should I set my CHARSET to utf8? I really do not know why, but I know if I don't do this way, nothing is returned. Nice but obscure!

Comment: Because UTF8 is the lingua franca on the web. Instead of cluttering the API with additional parameters and overhead, PHP (rigthly) uses the most common encoding, leaving to you the conversion burden if you use an uncommon (or an almost dead, as in your case) encoding.

Comment: The recommended way of doing this has now changed. I tried to edit this answer to include a link but was rejected. The correct way is in my answer below.

Comment: I also had this, ended up `changing the file encoding to utf-8` as the json result wasn't coming from a database query

Comment: As suggested above, `mysql_set_charset` would be a better alternative:
`$conn = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);`

Comment: This solved my problem but all my `varchar` fields have collation set to 'utf8_bin'. Is there something that can be done to the database itself to avoid running into issues like this?

Comment: @VeeK it is not enough to have your fields stored in UTF-8: you must [configure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/#example-changing-the-default-character-set-to-utf-8) your server to **answer** to clients in UTF-8. AFAIK stock mysql and mariadb use latin1.

Answer (score 120):

If you have at least PHP 5.5, you can use [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php), which will return a string describing the problem.

If you don't have 5.5, but are on/above 5.3, you can use [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to see what the problem is.

It will return an integer, that you can use to identify the problem in the [function's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). Currently (2012.01.19), the identifiers are:

```
0 = JSON_ERROR_NONE
1 = JSON_ERROR_DEPTH
2 = JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH
3 = JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR
4 = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8
```

These can change in future versions, so it's better to consult the manual.

If you are below 5.3, you are out of luck, there is no way to ask what the error was.

Answer (score 19):

ntd's anwser didn't solve my problem. For those in same situation, here is how I finally handled this error:
Just utf8_encode each of your results.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had encoding problems too. w/ mixed encoding. solution i found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3521396/776345

Answer (score 10):

You should pass utf8 encoded string in json_encode. You can use `utf8_encode` and `array_map()` function like below:

```
<?php
    $encoded_rows = array_map('utf8_encode', $rows);
    echo json_encode($encoded_rows);
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

few day ago I have the SAME problem with 1 table.

Firstly try:

```
echo json_encode($rows);
echo json_last_error();  // returns 5 ?
```

If last line returns 5, **problem is with your data**. I know, your tables are in UTF-8, but **not entered data**. For example the input was in txt file, but created on Win machine with stupid encoding (in my case Win-1250 = CP1250) and this data has been entered into the DB.

Solution? Look for new data (excel, web page), **edit source txt file** via PSPad (or whatever else), **change encoding to UTF-8**, delete all rows and now put data from original. Save. **Enter into DB**.

You can also only change encoding to utf-8 and then change all rows manually (give cols with special chars - desc, ...). Good for slaves...

Comment: or use [`JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR` option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters) to see the problem (eg. the field with UTF8 will be null).

Answer (score 5):

For anyone using PDO, the solution is similar to [ntd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972335/5313933).

From the [PHP PDO::__construct page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), as a comment from the user *Kiipa at live dot com*:

> To get UTF-8 charset you can specify that in the DSN.
>
> $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;**charset=UTF8**");

Answer (score 4):

AHHH!!! This looks so wrong it hurts my head. Try something more like this...

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$result = mysql_query('SELECT `id`, `name`, `description`, `icon` FROM `staff` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20') or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

- When iterating over `mysql_num_rows` you should use `<` not `<=`. You should also cache this value (save it to a variable) instead of having it re-count every loop. Who knows what it's doing under the hood... (might be efficient, I'm not really sure)
- You don't need to copy out each value explicitly like that... you're just making this harder on yourself. If the query is returning more values than you've listed there, list only the ones you want in your SQL.
- `mysql_fetch_array` returns the values both by `key` and by `int`. You not using the indices, so don't fetch em.

If this really is a problem with `json_encode`, then might I suggest replacing the body of the loop with something like

```
$rows[] = array_map('htmlentities',$row);
```

Perhpas there are some special chars in there that are mucking things up...

Comment: [{"id":"4","name":"Noter 2","description":null,"icon":"http:\/\/images.apple.com\/webapps\/productivity\/images\/noter2_20091223182720-thumb.jpg","date":"1262032317","company":"dBelement, LLC","companyurl":"http:\/\/dbelement.com\/","appurl":"http:\/\/noter2.dbelement.com"},{"id":"3","name":"Noter 2","description":null,"icon":"http:\/\/images.apple.com\/webapps\/productivity\/images\/noter2_20091223182720-thumb.jpg","date":"1262032317","company":"dBelement, LLC","companyurl":"http:\/\/dbelement.com\/","appurl":"http:\/\/noter2.dbelement.com"}]

Comment: @tarnfield: Well, is that what you want or not? Oh..you've got some additional info in there...here... let me fix that for you.

Comment: yeah "description" returns `null`

Comment: If the description is returning `null` then it probably *is* `null`. Try `echo $row['description'].'<br/>';` in that loop and see what it says.

Comment: if i do that, it echoes our the descriptions fine :)

Comment: Amended question again...try that.

Comment: Well, then you've baffled me. Play with some of the `json_encode` options: `JSON_HEX_QUOT, JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_AMP, JSON_HEX_APOS, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: The options parameter was added in PHP 5.3; you must be using an older version. Sorry dude ;) I give up.

Comment: hi, this answer saved my life, thank you. I was having the same problem here. I had values with non-utf8 chars like "Validação de Formulários". I know this question is a little bit old now, but that's the awesomeness of internet!!

Answer (score 4):

The PHP.net recommended way of setting the charset is now this:

[mysqli_set_charset('utf8')](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Answer (score 1):

For me, an issue where json_encode would return null encoding of an entity was because my jsonSerialize implementation fetched entire objects for related entities; I solved the issue by making sure that I fetched the ID of the related/associated entity and called ->toArray() when there were more than one entity associated with the object to be json serialized. Note, I'm speaking about cases where one `implements JsonSerializable` on entities.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem and the solution was to use my own function instead of `json_encode()`

```
echo '["' . implode('","', $row) . '"]';
```