# json_encode returning null with Postgres database and php

Tags: php, postgresql, json

I am referring to this question [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null), and I have the same problem, except that I use postgre database and can't seem to get this working.

This is my php function which is querying the database:

```
public function getCashData($id, $date)
{
    if ($this->openConnection()){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cash_register (". $id .", '". $date ."');";

        $result = pg_query($query);
        if (!$result){
                return false;
        }

        return pg_fetch_all($result);
    }
}
```

I call this function like this:

```
$cashReport = getCashReport($id, $date);

$cashReport = array_map('utf8_encode' , $casaReport); //**note: please read below
echo json_encode($casaReport);
```

**This was working perfectly when I was returning only one row of result (and not all like now), but now when I'm returning an array of rows this array_map function (which I found in the above mentioned link) is not working as it expects an array and not an array of arrays.

Can you guys help me solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have to run your array through `utf8_encode`? I think `json_encode` will handle that.

Comment: @Shef: actually, it won't because of the reasons explain in the link I gave in the question. Just to give you an example, I will get output: "colin":null,"colout":"1500". And you see this null? Well, this is giving me problems later in the script. I need this to be "colin":"","colout":"1500". So "" instead of null.

Comment: You don't solve your problems with more problems, but with solving what is causing it in the first place. Change your database collation to `UTF8` if you know you will be getting `utf8` characters. This will solve all the problems from the root.

Comment: @Shef: actually, I am not having any utf8 characters in any of my tables, and also, to be noted, I have my database set to this collation: en_US.UTF-8. I just used that solution from the (again) above mentioned link and that worked, that's why I was trying it this time also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in the end as I was forced to "fix" it asap:

```
$json = json_encode($cashReport);
$jsonEscapedNulls = str_replace('null', '""', $json);
echo $jsonEscapedNulls;
```

Now, I understand that "fixes" aren't solutions but I had no other choice in a give period of time :(. So if someone gives an answer which will work not as a fix but as a general solution I will be grateful. Until then, this will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function encode_items(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = utf8_encode($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($cashReport, 'encode_items');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to "tell" the postgre server to send the data utf-8 encoded.
see http://docs.php.net/pg_set_client_encoding

Comment: thank you for your answer but this unfortunately didn't help.