# php, Jso_encode($html) returning informaton:null

Tags: php, html, json, null, encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [json_encode is returning NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null)

We have a php web-service running that communicates with a iPhone app.
I am encoding all the desired data into json with json_encode.
But when I try to encode something that contains HTML tags I get null as value.

I know this got something to do with our php version we are running 5.2.3 if I recall correctly, and I know this is fixed in version 5.4.

So my question is, can this be done easily without upgrading our php version.

Comment: Is using `htmlspecialchars` or `strip_tags` an option?

Comment: try getting the error using [json_last_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: Like mario said this is indeed a Duplicate, thanks for pointing to the correct answer. +1 for mario