# echo json_encode() is returning NULL

Tags: php

I am trying to pass data to a php page via ajax, the data gets inserted to the database, then I need to pick up the last insert and pass the back to update a select menu with that last insert selected.  The database gets updated correctly, but Im getting a NULL return for the echo json_echo($data);

Been stuck on this all day, would really appreciate the help!!!

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

      $company_id   = $_POST['company_id'];
      $patient_id   = $_POST['addpatient_id'];
      $first_name   = $_POST['addpatient_firstname'];
      $last_name    = $_POST['addpatient_lastname'];
      $dob          = $_POST['addpatient_dob'];
      $updated      = $_POST['patient_added'];


      $update = array();
      array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');

      foreach($update_data as $field=>$data) {
          $update[] = '`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
      }

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `lab`.`patients` (`company_id`, `patient_firstname`, `patient_lastname`, `patient_dob`, `patient_added`) VALUES ('$company_id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$dob', '$updated')");
      $last_patient_id = mysql_insert_id();

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT `patient_id`, `patient_firstname`, `patient_lastname`, `patient_dob` FROM `patients` WHERE `patient_id` = $last_patient_id");
      $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
      echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null

Comment: Check what's inside your var with `var_dump($data)` as a first thing.

Comment: @moonwave99 var_dump returns NULL.  I believe mysql_insert_id is not picking up the last insert id.  The database is getting inserted correctly, but this has been driving me crazy all day.  If I move the last "}" bracket above the INSERT I get the json_encode I am expecting.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte the database is encoded properly.  Any thoughts?

Comment: My next guess is that your conditional is evaluating to false. var_dump($_POST, $errors). Also, you do not need to use any comparison with empty(). Just do: if( !empty($_POST) && !empty($errors) )

Comment: Well, if `$data` is empty, what's in `$result` for each loop?  And if that's empty, then what's in `$last_patient_id`?

Comment: And the standard disclaimer about the `mysql_*` methods being deprecated . . .

Comment: I agree with @MatthewBlancarte, fix your boolean zen, ie, dont do false === false type of stuff.  

I do not thing that is your problem though because it wouldn't run the insert and since you say the database is being updated we know it is entering the if statement

Comment: @Adam check `$last_patient_id` value: is it set? If so, have you got such record in your db? There lies the problem.

Comment: @Adam What is the result of var_dump($_POST, $errors);? Also, inside of your conditional, just do var_dump( 'got here' ); to see how far this program goes.

Comment: @moonwave99 when I run the page without the conditional if statement, the database get filled with a blank entry but it auto increments and then returns `[{"patient_id":"16","patient_firstname":"","patient_lastname":"","patient_dob":"0000-00-00"}]`

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Thank you, I updated my code.  Is that just a better way to code the conditional statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_encode returns false if an error happened ([php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).  I would start there.

```
$json_string = json_encode( $data );
if( $json_string ){
   echo $json_string;
}else{
   echo "Error";
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($data);
   echo "</pre>";
}
```

That should at least lead you a way to debug.

EDIT: Also try add this to the beginning of the function all

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

This will help display errors that the mysql is throwing.

EDIT: I wanted to just fix spelling, but since I need 6 characters minimum I will mention http://jsonlint.com/ to validate what you're putting into json_encode

Comment: I get a return of [null].  I think the mysql_insert_id is not picking up the last insert, which in turn is not coming back with any query result.  Any thoughts?

Comment: you sure it is AUTO_INCREMENTING right?  if you add  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); to the php at the beginning of the function call it might display a helpful error