# Why do Norwegian characters inserted into a database with MySQL dump get corrupted?

Tags: php, mysql, json, jsonp

Inserting `Norwegian characters` in my application through browser input (`php`) works fine (`json` data subsequently returned by the server is correct). But when I insert data  using `MYSQL dump` the records get corrupted, and json returned by the server then shows `NULL` in place of the `Norwegian characters`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just Norwegian characters or any foreign characters?

Comment: Not only Norwegian characters it's same for Arabic and similar..

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a character encoding issue. Which character encoding are you using?

Perhaps try [this](http://nathan.rambeck.org/blog/1-preventing-encoding-issues-mysqldump)?

Comment: Hi MMacdonald, I'm using - utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Have you checked that the character encoding of the dump file is also UTF8? Both the file and the database should have matching encodings. http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ is a good tool for checking the file encoding.

Comment: Hi,
I checked a lot of time Both database having utf8.

Comment: As well data is looking good in table .. but it's printing null in php json responce

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null

Comment: Now little bit i moved ahead by using  - 
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
OR
$pdo->exec("set names utf8");

Now output is coming as code - "R\u00c5KV\u00c5G" for "RÅKVÅG"

Comment: Good, u00C5 is the correct code for 'Å'. Your JSON decoder (e.g. web browser) should decode the unicode escape for you - have you tried? If you need to print unescaped unicode directly using PHP, look at the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option for json_encode() in the PHP docs (php 5.4.0 or later).