# Read JSON data from a text file and output to array

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [json_encode is returning NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null)

I'm trying to read JSON data from my text file 'signups.txt' and I'm using the following below. I want to grab the data from my text file and output the data in a foreach loop. Here's my code so far, I'm not 100% sure how to go about it.

```
$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('includes/signups.txt'), true);
```

**My data:**

```
{"name":"John Smith","studentid":"10358595","fbid":"1284556651"}
```

I'm thinking the following:

- Get file data as a string Encode into JSON maybe?
- Put the JSON data into an array using 'true'
- And then decode so that I can use the data

Sorry for been so vague but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for online. I apologise if the post is too brief. I'll do my best to add anything that I might have missed out. Thanks.

**Edit:** In terms of my current code, I just get null when I var_dump it.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code ?  The code works wrong ad returns `$json_data` as array ???

Comment: Just updated my situation, if I var dump what I currently have it just shows null.

Comment: try `echo '<pre>';print_r($json_data);echo '</pre>';` it gives `Array
(
    [name] => John Smith
    [studentid] => 10358595
    [fbid] => 1284556651
)` here

Comment: You can not get null .. `var_dump($json_data)` just have your code ... whats is the output ?

Comment: I just seem to get: <pre></pre>

Comment: Is that all the data you have in `signups.txt` ??? is there is more

Comment: If I use: 

$json_data = file_get_contents('includes/signups.txt');
$json_output = json_decode($json_data, true);
var_dump($json_data);

Then it shows the data.

Comment: What version og PHP are you using ?

Comment: Tested on that version it works ??

Comment: Very strange. I'm not quite sure what to do then. I'll try figure it out and then update, thanks for the help.

Comment: are you sure it works when you separate the variables ??? .. It would better to see your full code .. you can add it to pastebin

Comment: Here's what I currently have: http://pastebin.com/auGi421u

Answer (score 1):

From your Script http://pastebin.com/auGi421u

It shows you are having errors reading file but you don't know because you are outputting `print_r($json_data);` instead of `print_r($json_output)`

You can try this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");

$file = 'log.txt';

if (!is_file($file) xor !is_readable($file)) {
    trigger_error("File Not readable");
}

$data = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same problem. I just get NULL - using your code.

Comment: 5KB. I can't seem to figure it out, I'll try again in the morning, maybe I can get it working with a fresh mind.