# PHP: Can't put html stored in database into array. Get 'null'

Tags: php, arrays

I have some html I have stored in a database. I'm retrieving it using the following code:

```
include('globals.php');
$callback = isset($_REQUEST['callback'])?$_REQUEST['callback']:FALSE;
$page_id=$_REQUEST['page_id'];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT html FROM pages WHERE page_id=$page_id")->fetch_object();
$html = $result->html;
$output = array("html"=>$html);
if($callback){
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($output) . ');';
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

The json_encode returns simply {"html":null} If I echo out the $html variable itself the html code is there. However, if I put an echo for $output right after I set it I get Array("html":null). So, something is happening to the html when it's being written to the array.

Comment: try to turn on error reporting ''error_reporting(E_ALL);''. I suspect a function is failing silently (particularly json_encode).

Comment: Right after `$result = ...`, add `var_dump($result);exit`; and check what's coming out there.

Comment: It's coming out of the result just fine. As I mentioned I put an echo after setting the variable $html. It showed the full content of the variable as expected. All the html was there. Then I put an echo after setting the $output array. That returned Array("html":null). So I'm getting the info from the database just fine. Something is going wrong when it's trying to store it in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dug around and found the answer on a somewhat related thread. That answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972335/469219

It uses the older mysql_query syntax instead of the newer mysqli. My updated code looks like this:

```
include('globals.php');
$callback = isset($_REQUEST['callback'])?$_REQUEST['callback']:FALSE;
$page_id=$_REQUEST['page_id'];
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT html FROM pages WHERE page_id=$page_id")->fetch_object();
$html = $result->html;
$output = array("html"=>$html);
if($callback){
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($output) . ');';
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Notice the new line `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');`