# PHP - Service returns NULL when row contains special characters

Tags: php, sql

I have a MySQL database hosted on a server. On table PERSON, I have the NAME column. One of the rows, has a name with the character "Ñ".

I'm working with a PHP Webservice that returns all the rows of that table, it works fine, but when one of the values contains a "Ñ", it returns null.

For Example:
TABLE: Person. (ID - NAME)
1 - John
2 - Paul
3 - Iñaki

The PHP webservice returns Johm, Paul and null.

If I connect to the database from SQLyog or other software, I see the real values, John, Paul and Iñaki, so the problem is when the PHP Service returns the values of the table.

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');


$server = "*****";
$username = "******";
$password = "********";
$database = "********";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM person";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

Any help?

Comment: did you tell your client what charset you've encoded everything in? you have to use the SAME charset throughout, or connect individual stages with appropriate charset translation logic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [json\_encode is returning NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null)

Comment: yea! it was that! thanks! I guess I gotta start doin better researches, ha?