# json_encode returning null values for form inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, forms

I'm having issues with my first AJAX form submission attempts.  I have a basic HTML form (http://jsfiddle.net/hmp4A/1/), a little JS, and a php validation file. In doing some tests, I see that some of my form inputs are coming back as "null" in my console.log, while others are not.

I've seen a few threads on this here, like [json_encode is returning NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null) and have tried specifically encoding variables in UTF8, tried converting my form string into an int using intval(), among other things.  Some of these changes result in the "percentequities" field being null, some result in it being 0.  json_last_error() is returning a 0 code.

It seems like values in the first  pass fine, but anything else does not. What am I missing?

Edit: to be clear: If I change this to a regular POST event to validate.php, and print out the $_POST variable, the inputs look fine. To add to the mystery:  If I take away the 'magic.js' and do a simple POST to 'validate.php', it successfully json_encodes all the inputs (I can see them in an echo statement of the json).  If I turn around and add back in 'magic.js' so that it tries an AJAX request, it gives null values for 'percentequities' again.

Here is 'validate.php':

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(0);
$time_start = microtime(true); 

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

if(!is_numeric($_POST["spending"])){
    $errors['spending']="Spending must be a numeric value. Please return to the input page and input only numbers and decimal points.";
}
if(!is_numeric($_POST["portfolio"])){
    $errors['portfolio']="Portfolio must be a numeric value. Please return to the input page and input only numbers and decimal points.";
}
if(!is_numeric($_POST["percentequities"])){
    $errors['percentequities']="Percent Equities must be a numeric value. Please return to the input page and input only numbers and decimal points.";
}
if(!is_numeric($_POST["percentbonds"])){
    $errors['percentbonds']="Percent Bonds must be a numeric value. Please return to the input page and input only numbers and decimal points.";
}
if(!($_POST["percentequities"]+$_POST["percentbonds"]==100)){
    $errors['allocationPercentageCheck']= "Allocation must add up to exactly 100%. Please return to the input page and correct these values.";
}

if(!($_POST["percentequities"]+$_POST["percentbonds"]==100)){
    $errors['allocationPercentageCheck']= "Allocation must add up to exactly 100%. Please return to the input page and correct these values.";
}

if ( ! empty($errors)) {
// if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
$data['success'] = false;
$data['errors']  = $errors;
$data['percentequities'] = $_POST['percentequities'];
$data['portfolio'] = $_POST["portfolio"];
$data['jsonlasterror'] = json_last_error();
} else {
// if there are no errors process our form, then return a message
// show a message of success and provide a true success variable
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated yet hopefully helpful tips: 1) `error_reporting(0);` is of little help when debugging. 2) You're using the `?:` operator wrong—it kind of works for you by pure chance.

Comment: error_reporting(0) isn't normally there. When I was testing the json return, error reporting was sending back a lot of extraneous data making it hard for me to see $data['percentequities'] (which is the null value).   

Am I using that wrong? I'll re-read the docs on it.  I usually use plain ole if/else brackets, but was trying the shorthand version.

Comment: That extraneous data is also called error messages and they're there to help you diagnose issues ;-)

Comment: maybe the input name is different

Comment: @Wilmer, according to the code I laid out... the input name is the same as when I define it in the $data array.

Comment: @Alvaro :  Fair enough.  Errors are showing "undefined index" for percentequities, but not portfolio. Hmm...

Comment: try [json_last_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: @mamdouh: I mentioned in the OP that json_last_error returned a code of 0.

Comment: Are you using `json_last_error()` *before* `json_encode()`?

Comment: Alvaro: I was doing it before json_encode, but when it was mentioned I tried it afterwards and still reported a 0.

Comment: To add to the mystery:  If I take away the 'magic.js' and do a simple POST to 'validate.php', it successfully json_encodes all the inputs (I can see them in an echo statement of the json).  If I turn around and add back in 'magic.js' so that it tries an AJAX request, it gives null values for 'percentequities' again.

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly, but as I said this was my first attempt.  I didn't have all the variables defined in the "var formData = {}" section of the JS.  I naively thought that simply having the PHP file take the POST data and json_encode it, it would come across the AJAX call without defining it.  I was wrong.