# PHP PDO - Json encode with UTF-8

Tags: php, json, encoding, pdo, utf-8

I have this data to datatable cell: `AlgoVital  Plus čćš` so some characters is utf-8

Here's my database schema

[image]

After that I make json file with php and send it to fronted:

```
//header
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
...
...
//at the end of php file:
 $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    //echo $jsonTable;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $jsonTable;
```

and HTML head is OK too:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

but I cant show data with utf-8 characters... WHy?

JSON is not format with utf-8 characers... etc. where I have some characters like čćšž then I just get NULL at JSON file, when I use json encode

How I can solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [json\_encode is returning NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oX6LIlt.png

Comment: Why would you send text/html content type header when the content is application/json?

Comment: hm, I dont know, I will delete this row

Comment: @johnymile Now show some proof that the data was properly entered as UTF-8, a screenshot of the data in the DB.

Comment: I am with @JuanMendes here in that show have not shown enough context/debugging info to determine if the problem is DB-related or JSON encoding related.  PHP's json_encode assumes a UTF-8 character set, so typically there shuold not be a problem encoding UTF-8 characters to their JSON escape sequences.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Vkb0R6O.png - please see last enter record, there is utf-8 characters

Comment: OK. So your collations look OK, but what is the character set of the table?  Can you past your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` information? Also, assuming this everything is correct with database set up, have you demonstrated that you can output these characters directly in response without JSON-encoding?  In other words, what led you to believe that the problem lies in the JSON-encoding step?

Comment: the problem was been with data, when I add it manualz then wont work, but when data comes from ajax when I add data, then works fine, THANKS  VERZ MUCH FOR HELP

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$table = '[{name: "PHP",version: 5.6}]'; //your json data
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$myObj = json_decode($jsonTable);
echo $myObj->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$table = utf8_encode($table);
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Comment: no, when i write $table['data'] = utf8_encode($rows); I get JSON with NO data

Comment: I copied your code. So it works for me:

$array = Array();
$array["test"] = "AlgoVital  Plus čćš";

 $jsonTable = json_encode($array);

echo $jsonTable;

Comment: @zamarrowski That means you don't need to call `utf_encode` ?

Comment: Yes, in my example is not necessary.