# json_encode on array returns nothing

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I'm trying to get an entire table from mysqli and return it JSON encoded like this:

```
$result = $db->query('select * from categories');

$categories = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    // echo json_encode($row); // Returns the row in JSON.
    $categories[] = array('ID' => $row->ID, 'name' => $row->name);
}

echo count($categories); // Returns 28, the amount of categories on the DB
echo json_encode($categories); // returns ""
```

But when I apply `json_encode` on the entire array, it returns nothing.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null

Comment: plesae do a `print_r($categories)` and update your question with the output

Comment: Do you have special characters in name or id?

Comment: @AlexAndrei or better `var_export($categories)` because of `false` and `""` values is not visible in print_r

Comment: try use `json_last_error()` and `json_last_error_msg` to see if there any errors

Comment: @troyz  ***If $categories has a complex structure (perhaps with many layers of nesting),*** you may want to ***take advantage of*** the extra arguments accepted by the json_encode Function especially ***the 3rd parameter ($depth).***