# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input : passing sql table rows to JavaScript file but cannot spot the error

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am passing sql table rows to a javascript file to be shown once the website page has loaded:

php code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `publication_information`";
    $pubs = $conn->query($sql);
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pubs)) {
      $existing_publications[] = $row;
    }  
        $willies = json_encode($existing_publications);
        echo $willies;
```

javascript code:

```
function WORK(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/shoba/publications.php";
    
    
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // Check if the request is completed and successful
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        // Parse the JSON response
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
 
        // Do something with the data
        console.log(data+" success");
      } else {
          console.log(error);
      }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
    alert("reached function end");
}
```

on calling the function, the alert is reached but i get the uncaught error:

```
VM65:1  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

But I cannot spot what is wrong, to my knowledge , since I used an auto function it should work, but it sadly does not. Can you help tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Add `console.log(xhr.responseText)` to see the actual response. There may be something before the JSON.

Comment: Or use the Network tab to see the raw response.

Answer (score 0):

Unless guaranteed to be properly formed, it is recommended to use [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block when parsing a JSON string.

The example below gives you what the problem was and the content causing the parser to fail.

```
var responseText = xhr.responseText;

try {
  var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
  console.log(data);
} catch (ex) {
  console.warn(ex.message);
  console.info('"' + responseText + '"');
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the PHP side but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972006/json-encode-is-returning-null), we see that the `json_encode` may return `null`. Have you checked what JSON string is returned if `$pubs` has no items or `null`?