# Some unclear PHP syntax

Tags: php, syntax, nowdoc

I am a PHP beginner and saw on the forum this PHP expression:

My PHP version is 5.2.X ()

```
$regex = <<<'END'
/
  ( [\x00-\x7F]                 # single-byte sequences   0xxxxxxx
  | [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]      # double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
  | [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}   # triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
  | [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}   # quadruple-byte sequence 11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3 
  )
| ( [\x80-\xBF] )               # invalid byte in range 10000000 - 10111111
| ( [\xC0-\xFF] )               # invalid byte in range 11000000 - 11111111
/x
END;
```

Is this code correct? What do these strange (for me) constructions like `<<<`, `'END'`, `/`, `/x`, and `END;` mean?

My PHP version does not support nowdoc, how should I replace this expression? without quotes `'END'` $regex became `NULL`

I recieve:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_SL in
>   /home/vhosts/mysite.com/public_html/mypage.php
>   on line X

Thanks

Comment: While this is valid PHP, for sure, a vast majority of that code is actually a regular expression and understanding regexes is somewhat independent from understanding PHP.  Most languages in common use today have a regex engine built in that accepts similar expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_SL in
>   /home/vhosts/mysite.com/public_html/mypage.php
>   on line X

This comes from the 's around END.  This is called nowdoc, which was added in PHP 5.3.  Since you're using PHP 5.2, and this regex uses '\x', you'll need a quoted string or you'll need to escape the '\'s.

An example of the regex as a quoted string, used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401716/1338292):

```
$regex = '/
( [\x00-\x7F]                 # single-byte sequences   0xxxxxxx
  | [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]      # double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
  | [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}   # triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
  | [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}   # quadruple-byte sequence 11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3
  )
| ( [\x80-\xBF] )               # invalid byte in range 10000000 - 10111111
| ( [\xC0-\xFF] )               # invalid byte in range 11000000 - 11111111
/x
';
```

The "/" and "/x" portions are control characters in the regex.  The "/"s mark the beginning and end, and the meaning of the x flag (PCRE_EXTENDED) is defined in: http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: +1 for recognizing the difference between nowdoc and heredoc!

Answer (score 5):

`<<<` and `END` are called *heredoc syntax* - a way of quoting a large amount of data to a variable.

```
$mytext = <<<TXT

this is my text and it
can be many lines
etc
etc

TXT;
```

The three characters (here TXT, END in your example) can be whatever you like although they must be alphanumeric as far as I'm aware.

Read more at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 3):

It's [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

The `<<< 'END'` says that it's the start of a string and that everything until the next appearance of "END" will be part of the string (even newlines).

The `/` and `/x` are actually part of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what other users have said about it being heredoc syntax (typically used for large strings that would otherwise require a lot of escaping), the code is defining a regular expression using "/" as the deliminator.

the "/x" at the end is closing the regular expression and then telling the regex engine to execute it in "free-spacing mode".  Other possible options would have been /i for case-insensitive or /m for multi-line mode.

You can read more about PHP's regex engine here:

[Using Regular Expressions in PHP](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)

Comment: heredoc, newdoc... What difference between them.. `'END'` or just `END`?

Comment: $vars within heredocs are expanded as if the string were in "double quotes". $ in nowdocs is treated like $ in 'single quotes'. (Or vice versa, I haven't looked at 5.3 recently.)

Comment: my php version does not support nowdoc, how should I replace this expression? without quotes '' $regex became NULL