# Regex to accept values on ASCII value range

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regex to accept a text which has only characters, with ASCII values between 32-125 and with a minimum text length of 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036925/accept-characters-only-available-on-the-english-keyword-using-javascript) answers your question

```
/^[\x20-\x7D]+$/
```