# Replacement for javascript escape?

Tags: javascript, encoding, escaping, mailto

I know that the [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) function has been deprecated and that you should use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent instead. However, the encodeUri and encodeUriComponent doesn't do the same thing as escape.

I want to create a mailto link in javascript with Swedish åäö. Here are a comparison between escape, encodeURIComponent and encodeURI:

```js
var subject="åäö";
var body="bodyåäö";

console.log("mailto:?subject="+escape(subject)+"&body=" + escape(body));
console.log("mailto:?subject="+encodeURIComponent(subject)+"&body=" + encodeURIComponent(body));
console.log("mailto:?subject="+encodeURI(subject)+"&body=" + encodeURI(body));
```

```
Output:
mailto:?subject=My%20subject%20with%20%E5%E4%F6&body=My%20body%20with%20more%20characters%20and%20swedish%20%E5%E4%F6
mailto:?subject=My%20subject%20with%20%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6&body=My%20body%20with%20more%20characters%20and%20swedish%20%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6
mailto:?subject=My%20subject%20with%20%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6&body=My%20body%20with%20more%20characters%20and%20swedish%20%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6
```

Only the mailto link created with "escape" opens a properly formatted mail in Outlook using IE or Chrome. When using encodeURI or encodeURIComponent the subject says:

```
My subject with Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶
```

and the body is also looking messed up.

Is there some other function besides escape that I can use to get the working mailto link?

Comment: What encoding are you using, have you tried using `utf-8`?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I did notice now that escape is not working in Firefox, so I'll have to use encodeURIComponent in the Firefox case. Error in Firefox:
_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMLocation.href]

Comment: The best solution I've come up with is to define my own escape function instead of using the deprecated one. Here is one example of how the escape function could be implemented:
http://cwestblog.com/2011/05/23/escape-unescape-deprecated/

Answer (score 12):

`escape()` is defined in section [B.2.1.2 escape](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-escape-string) and the [introduction text of Annex B](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers) says:

> ... All of the language features and behaviours specified in this annex have one or more undesirable characteristics and in the absence of legacy usage would be removed from this specification. ...

For characters, whose code unit value is 0xFF or less, `escape()` produces a two-digit escape sequence: `%xx`. This basically means, that `escape()` converts a string containing only characters from `U+0000` to `U+00FF` to an percent-encoded string using the *latin-1* encoding.

For characters with a greater code unit, the four-digit format `%uxxxx` is used. This is not allowed within the `hfields` section (where subject and body are stored) of an `mailto:`-URI (as defined in [RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-2)):

```
mailtoURI    = "mailto:" [ to ] [ hfields ]
to           = addr-spec *("," addr-spec )
hfields      = "?" hfield *( "&" hfield )
hfield       = hfname "=" hfvalue
hfname       = *qchar
hfvalue      = *qchar
...
qchar        = unreserved / pct-encoded / some-delims
some-delims  = "!" / "$" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*"
               / "+" / "," / ";" / ":" / "@"
```

`unreserved` and `pct-encoded` are defined in [STD66](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#page-50):

```
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
```

A percent sign is only allowed if it is directly followed by two hexdigits, percent followed by `u` is not allowed.

Using a self-implemented version, that behaves exactly like `escape` doesn't solve anything - instead just continue to use `escape`, it won't be removed anytime soon.

---

To summerise: Your previous usage of `escape()` generated latin1-percent-encoded mailto-URIs if all characters are in the range `U+0000` to `U+00FF`, otherwise an invalid URI was generated (which might still be correctly interpreted by some applications, if they had javascript-encode/decode compatibility in mind).

It is more correct (no risk of creating invalid URIs) and future-proof, to generate UTF8-percent-encoded mailto-URIs using `encodeURIComponent()` (don't use `encodeURI()`, it does not escape `?`, `/`, ...). [RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#page-6) requires usage of UTF-8 in many places (but allows other encodings for "MIME encoded words and for bodies in composed email messages").

Example:

```js
text_latin1="Swedish åäö"
text_other="Emoji "

document.getElementById('escape-latin-1-link').href="mailto:?subject="+escape(text_latin1);
document.getElementById('escape-other-chars-link').href="mailto:?subject="+escape(text_other);
document.getElementById('utf8-link').href="mailto:?subject="+encodeURIComponent(text_latin1);
document.getElementById('utf8-other-chars-link').href="mailto:?subject="+encodeURIComponent(text_other);

function mime_word(text){
  q_encoded = encodeURIComponent(text) //to utf8 percent encoded
  .replace(/[_!'()*]/g, function(c){return '%'+c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();})// encode some more chars as utf8
  .replace(/%20/g,'_') // mime Q-encoding is using underscore as space
  .replace(/%/g,'='); //mime Q-encoding uses equal instead of percent
  return encodeURIComponent('=?utf-8?Q?'+q_encoded+'?=');//add mime word stuff and escape for uri
}

//don't use mime_word for body!!!
document.getElementById('mime-word-link').href="mailto:?subject="+mime_word(text_latin1);
document.getElementById('mime-word-other-chars-link').href="mailto:?subject="+mime_word(text_other);
```

```html
<a id="escape-latin-1-link">escape()-latin1</a><br/>
<a id="escape-other-chars-link">escape()-emoji</a><br/>
<a id="utf8-link">utf8</a><br/>
<a id="utf8-other-chars-link">utf8-emoji</a><br/>
<a id="mime-word-link">mime-word</a><br/>
<a id="mime-word-other-chars-link">mime-word-emoji</a><br/>
```

For me, the UTF-8 links and the Mime-Word links work in Thunderbird. Only the plain UTF-8 links work in Windows 10 builtin Mailapp and my up-to-date version of Outlook.

Comment: In a test of Chrome 74.0.3729.169 (64-bit) on Windows 10, only the UTF-8 links worked to produce the correct unicode characters.  The other resulted in either undetermined characters (�) or just kept the string of %hex escape codes.

Comment: @CPerkins You specify the browser, you used to click on the links, but AFAIK the behavior is irrelevant of the browser. The result does however depend on the mail-client that is opened when interpreting `mailto:`-links. It would therefore be nice, if you could specify which mail-client is opened, when you click on the links. If the links open a new tab in your browser, that means a webmail service is registered as `mailto:`-handler. In that case, please specify, which webmail service is used. (gmail.com or outlook.com or roundcube or ... ?)

Comment: I intended to mention that I was using a browser-based mail client, so in that case the browser's behavior and initial interpretation of the URI is definitely relevant. To explain further, the mailto URIs were produced and clicked in Firefox 67 which opened Chrome.  The browser is not irrelevant anyway, since this is all about producing the correct link within the browser, so between producing the URI to passing it off to the mailto client, I suppose there is a dependence on the browser there too.  FYI, I confirmed that Thunderbird correctly interprets the UTF-8 and mime-word URIs.

Answer (score 5):

To quote the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) directly...

> This function was used mostly for URL queries (the part of a URL following ?)—not for escaping ordinary String literals, ***which use the format "\xHH". (HH are two hexadecimal digits, and the form \xHH\xHH is used for higher-plane Unicode characters.)***

The problem you are experiencing is because `escape()` does not support the UTF-8 while `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` do.

**But to be absolutely clear**: ***never** use `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()`.*  Let's just try it out:

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('@#*'));
```

Input: `@#*`.  Output: `%40%23*`.  Ordinarily, once user input is cleansed, I feel like I can trust that cleansed input.  But if I ran `rm *` on my Linux system to delete a file specified by a user, that would literally delete all files on my system, even if I did the encoding 100% completely server-side.  This is a massive bug in `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`, which MDN Web docs clearly point with a solution.

Use [`fixedEncodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), when trying to encode a complete URL (i.e., all of `example.com?arg=val`), as defined and further explained at the [**MDN encodeURI() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)...

> ```
> function fixedEncodeURI(str) {
>    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
> }
> ```

Or, you may need to use use [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), when trying to encode part of a URL (i.e., the `arg` or the `val` in `example.com?arg=val`), as defined and further explained at the [**MDN encodeURIComponent() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)...

> ```
> function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
>  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
>    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
>  });
> }
> ```

If you are having trouble distinguishing what `fixedEncodeURI()`, `fixedEncodeURIComponent()`, and `escape()` do, I always like to simplify it with:

- `fixedEncodeURI()` : ***will not*** encode `+@?=:#;,$&` to their http-encoded equivalents (as `&` and `+` are common URL operators)
- `fixedEncodeURIComponent()` ***will*** encode `+@?=:#;,$&` to their http-encoded equivalents.

Comment: encodeURI is not a function to escape characters for usage in a shell (and neither was escape), it is used to encode data into a format suitable for usage as a URI parameter. Your "fixedEncodeURI" doesn't change anything about that either.

Comment: "*Ordinarily, once user input is cleansed, I feel like I can trust that cleansed input.*" - that's not how it works. You always have to escape strings if you are embedding them somewhere, **depending on the context**. They don't become "trusted" at some point. `encodeURIComponent` is totally fine (and recommended) for encoding strings in URIs. Do not use it for encoding strings in shell commands.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe useful:

```js
/**
 * Escape non printable char. eg: "\x08", "\xAAAA", "\r" or "A"
 * @param {number} code 
 * @returns {string}
 */
function escape(code) {
    if (code > 0x7f) {
        return `\\x${code.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')}`
    }
    const char = String.fromCharCode(code)
    const mayEscaped = JSON.stringify(char)
    if (mayEscaped != `"${char}"`) {
        if (mayEscaped.length == 4) {
            // escaped "\r"
            return mayEscaped.slice(1, 3)
        }
        // escaped "\u0000"
        return '\\x' + mayEscaped.slice(code > 0xff ? 3 : 5, 7)
    } else {
        return char
    }
}
```

Answer (score -8):

The escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use [encodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) or [encodeURIComponent()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) instead.

example

```
string:            "May/June 2016, Volume 72, Issue 3"
escape:            "May/June%202016%2C%20Volume%2072%2C%20Issue%203"
encodeURI:         "May/June%202016,%20Volume%2072,%20Issue%203"
encodeURIComponent:"May%2FJune%202016%2C%20Volume%2072%2C%20Issue%203"
```

source https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: Those two functions don't do the same thing as escape. The question even states this. Also, W3 schools is not a great resource to link to.

Comment: `s = 'a?b/c<d>e"f\'g'; console.log(escape(s), encodeURI(s), encodeURIComponent(s)) #=> a%3Fb/c%3Cd%3Ee%22f%27g a?b/c%3Cd%3Ee%22f'g a%3Fb%2Fc%3Cd%3Ee%22f'g`, only escape protects against XSS correctly (not possible to escape a quotes attribute)