# How can two visually identical bits of text be different to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, string, text, sublimetext2, clipboard

I have a sublime document with two identical file paths (2 seperate lines), if I copy one my app functionality works, if I copy the other it does not.

When I select one line and do cmd + d you would expect sublime to highlight both lines, as per normal functionality. It does not. This is also true in VC code, so something is different about these two lines.

I have tried myData.toString()
I tried JSON.parse but it didn't go well I couldn't figure it out

Here at the offending lines.

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Archive/Work/AE_Scripting/⁨Resources⁩/⁨CEP-Resources-master⁩/⁨CEP_8.x⁩/⁨Documentation

-Works
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Archive/Work/AE_Scripting/Resources/CEP-Resources-master/CEP_8.x/Documentation
```

Upon uploading an example file for this post I have now some new information, as you can see here

http://gravitystaging.com/uploadarea/test/examplefile.txt

Both lines now appear as

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Archive/Work/AE_Scripting/â¨Resourcesâ©/â¨CEP-Resources-masterâ©/â¨CEP_8.xâ©/â¨Documentation

-Works
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Archive/Work/AE_Scripting/Resources/CEP-Resources-master/CEP_8.x/Documentation
```

Although in any editor they look normal and identical. So how can I process this string to remove this.

Comment: Looks like the line was encoded in a different format than the second line. Have you edited the file with different operating systems (e.g. Linux and Windows)?

Comment: I'm not too sure where the first line came from possibly terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with the following thread

[How to remove invalid UTF-8 characters from a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670037/how-to-remove-invalid-utf-8-characters-from-a-javascript-string)

```
function cleanString(input) {
    var output = "";
    for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        if (input.charCodeAt(i) <= 127) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Its something I looked at early on but must have been using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your first string has some Unicode bidirectional marking characters in it: U+2068 and U+2069. You can use the `ord` function in Python to check for these:

```
>>> [ord(x) for x in '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Archive/Work/AE_Scripting/⁨Resources⁩/⁨CEP-Resources-master⁩/⁨CEP_8.x⁩/⁨Documentation']
[47, 86, 111, 108, 117, 109, 101, 115, 47, 77, 97, 99, 105, 110, 116, 111, 115, 104, 32, 72, 68, 47, 65, 114, 99, 104, 105, 118, 101, 47, 87, 111, 114, 107, 47, 65, 69, 95, 83, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 105, 110, 103, 47, 8296, 82, 101, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 115, 8297, 47, 8296, 67, 69, 80, 45, 82, 101, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 115, 45, 109, 97, 115, 116, 101, 114, 8297, 47, 8296, 67, 69, 80, 95, 56, 46, 120, 8297, 47, 8296, 68, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110]
```

See the ones that are 8000-something? Those are the Unicode markers you don't want.

If you just want plain ASCII, here's how I would do that in Python:

```
''.join(c for c in my_string if ord(c) < 256)
```

This strips out anything higher than U+00FF.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at using regex to remove all non-alphanumeric characters.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225734/9899022

Since the pasted text and additional characters are already in string format, attempting to parse it to JSON or calling .toString() won't change anything about the variable.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like regex is the answer. It's going to take a while to decipher the voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

If you `cat` your file in a (MacOS) bash terminal you will get identical lines. Running `encguess examplefile.txt` will tell you the format is UTF-8. Opening in it in SublimeText 3 with UTF-8 encoding will also show you identical lines.

But if you switch to **Western (Windows 1252)** encoding then you will get the exact same wrong symbols as in your example. So I guess you are using the wrong encoding to view your file.

How to switch encoding in SublimeText 3: 
File => Reopen With Encoding => Choose your Encoding (UTF-8)

**Edit**
If you want to remove the wrong characters from your given string, you can use `String.replace()`.

```js
str = "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Archive/Work/AE_Scripting/â¨Resourcesâ©/â¨CEP-Resources-masterâ©/â¨CEP_8.xâ©/â¨Documentation"

console.log("Before: ", str);

str = str.replace(/(â©)|(â¨)/g, "");
console.log("After: ", str);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I need to know how to convert the line with javascript.

Comment: Do you want to remove all the wrong chars using JavaScript? You could use a simple Regex to delete the unwanted characters `str.replace(/(â©)|(â¨)/g, "")`

Comment: This is incorrect: the correct encoding is UTF-8, which makes the control characters invisible (as they should be). Interpreting it as Windows 1252 turns them into the mojibake.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, updated my answer. Also, thanks for "mojibake" didn't know there is a name for it. It makes it easier to research!

Comment: Sorry does that mean ````str.replace(/(â©)|(â¨)/g, "")```` this line would work?

Comment: ````str.replace(/(â©)|(â¨)/g, "")```` doesn't actually work, because I can't guarantee the encoding type of the text coming in. the string is set by electrons clipboard.readText() so regex doesn't see these characters.

Comment: I just answered to your specific problem; removing these characters. You can easily create a regex that only allows for valid characters.