# How to get � symbol real value?

Tags: javascript

Im working with emojis and I get into situations where emojis can split into several parts (because emojis have `>1` length) and I end up with � symbol(s).

How to get the real (string) value of it?

---

If I understand it correctly, � symbol is a generic "broken" symbol that could have different value depending on situation. E.g the following hard-coded comparison doesn't work because while `myVar` would log out � symbol, underlaying value/string is different:

```
if (myVar === "�") // ...enter code here
```

Comment: See the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670037/how-to-remove-invalid-utf-8-characters-from-a-javascript-string

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Atom. Why?

Comment: Why are you splitting the characters and how are you doing it ?

Comment: @Solo Because I use sublime text and emojis are actually graphically rendered by the editor as a single character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character in a string can be replaced with its corresponding unicode escape sequence. e.g.,

```js
"A" === "\u0041"
```

However any character above the `0x0000 - 0xFFFF` range (e.g. emojis) needs to be broken down into a "surrogate pair". e.g.,

```js
"" === "\uD83C\uDF2F"
//         ^     ^
//         A     B
//
// A: first half
// B: second half
```

Which is why `"".length === 2`!

Put together these halves print a  on screen. However if you split them apart they become these "broken" symbols:

```js
"".split("")
//=>  ["�", "�"]
```

As you worked it out, the � symbol is the same face for many different values. To know what's behind the mask you can simply use `String#charCodeAt` e.g.,

```js
"".split("").map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
//=> [55356, 57135]
```

Or for their hex values:

```js
"".split("").map(c => c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))
//=> ["d83c", "df2f"]
```

#### How do you detect a broken emoji?

```js
"Hello ".slice(0, -1)
//=> "Hello �"
```

We can use a regular expression using the `u` flag and a [unicode property escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) to match a surrogate:

```js
const broken_emoji = /\p{Surrogate}/u;

broken_emoji.test("Hello ");
//=> false

broken_emoji.test("Hello ".slice(0, -1));
//=> true
```

Reading further

- https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode