# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token while parsing XML

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

**Update:-**
Seems like I have to give the URL which is returning me the xml. Here it is - [URL](http://applications.ukash.com/WhereToBuy/Markers.aspx?lat=53.34234&lng=-2.003&count=5&units=mi&cc=GB&l=partnername&search=Macclesfield)

---

I am getting SAXParseException when parsing an xml. The xml I am trying to parse is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers xmlns="">
    <marker name="" address1="" address2="" region="" country="" zip="" imgsrc="" lat="" lng="" distance="" />
    <marker name="" address1="" address2="" region="" country="" zip="" imgsrc="" lat="" lng="" distance="" />
    <marker name="" address1="" address2="" region="" country="" zip="" imgsrc="" lat="" lng="" distance="" />
    <marker name="" address1="" address2="" region="" country="" zip="" imgsrc="" lat="" lng="" distance="" />
    <marker name="" address1="" address2="" region="" country="" zip="" imgsrc="" lat="" lng="" distance="" />
</markers>
```

The code which I am using to parse this xml is as follows -

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ParserConfigurationException: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("SAXException: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("IOException: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return doc;
}
```

I am using same code to parse other xml data and it works. I couldn't understand what's there in this xml data which is stopping it to parse the data properly. I have checked the xml with many xml validators online too.

I must be missing something obvious here.

**EDIT:-**
The xml I am trying to parse is from a webservice(the name, address etc. are not actually empty). When I try to use the xml directly by hardcoding in the code itself, it works fine. But when trying to use it directly from webservice response, is not working for me.

**The exception:-**

```
10-09 20:39:50.328: W/System.err(16211): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@41941010) 
10-09 20:39:50.335: W/System.err(16211):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
10-09 20:39:50.335: W/System.err(16211):    at com.blackcobrastudios.ukash.WebService.XMLDataParser.getDomElement(XMLDataParser.java:159)
10-09 20:39:50.335: W/System.err(16211):    at com.blackcobrastudios.ukash.Manager.APICaller.processResult(APICaller.java:386)
10-09 20:39:50.335: W/System.err(16211):    at com.blackcobrastudios.ukash.Manager.APICaller.access$1(APICaller.java:385)
10-09 20:39:50.335: W/System.err(16211):    at com.blackcobrastudios.ukash.Manager.APICaller$SoapCaller.onPostExecute(APICaller.java:361)
10-09 20:39:50.335: W/System.err(16211):    at com.blackcobrastudios.ukash.Manager.APICaller$SoapCaller.onPostExecute(APICaller.java:1)
10-09 20:39:50.335: W/System.err(16211):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
10-09 20:39:50.343: W/System.err(16211):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
10-09 20:39:50.343: W/System.err(16211):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
10-09 20:39:50.343: W/System.err(16211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 20:39:50.343: W/System.err(16211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 20:39:50.343: W/System.err(16211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4536)
10-09 20:39:50.343: W/System.err(16211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 20:39:50.351: W/System.err(16211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 20:39:50.351: W/System.err(16211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
10-09 20:39:50.351: W/System.err(16211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
10-09 20:39:50.351: W/System.err(16211):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 20:39:50.351: E/SAXException:(16211): Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@41941010)
```

Comment: Could be the empty namespace declaration.  Also, are you sure it's utf-8?

Comment: I tried replacing the namespace with something which all my other xml have. I tried removing the xml altogether.

Comment: Also please check the update in the question.

Comment: Updated the url of xml. Please check it.

Comment: This is the same issue with the similar API - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in the encoding. The following answer explains it properly -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869127/1079901

I just have to call this regex on the response string -

```
response = response.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");
```

Thanks to [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) for such a perfect answer.

Comment: @Bachask8 is your problem similar to mine? I mean did you check the linked answer of BaluC which explains the issue. It was an encoding mismatch issue.

Comment: yeah, and it worked with this   `ByteArrayInputStream encXML = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmldatos.getBytes("UTF8"));`

Comment: So it was an encoding issue after all.

Comment: Hey Noob, Thanks a lot man... You saved my day. You are awesome

Comment: @coders Yes, I know I am awesome. Thanks for confirming it ;-)

Comment: I tried it. This is not the solution. SAXParseException occure anyway.

Comment: @RussiaDroneFlights This may be because of different encoding in your xml. You may wanna try a different regex to remove unwanted symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend abandoning the sax parser and using the Android officially supported [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).  Sax parser is not supported after Android Gingerbread (2.3.3)

Comment: I have tried it already, it's giving me XMLPullParserException. Please check the XML URL in the question.

Comment: You have `xmlns=""` If you want the parser to work, you need to define the xml namespace that defines the rules.  Most XML is compliant with `http:www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`  but you may need a different one.  If you don't identify the namespace, the parser won't know the rules to parse your xml.

Comment: How do I add the rules? I can't change the webservice, so I have to make changes in the resultant string.

Comment: You don't need to add the rules, the namespace already defines them.  The parser uses the namespace to know which rules to use.

Comment: My app kept on crashing because it `"doesn't support the required security features: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities"`  .. now this explain why, thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the **XML** contains **Unicode** characters such as **arabic** or **Persian** letters, `StringReader` would make an exception. In these cases, pass the **InputStream** straightly to the **Document** object

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying to incorporate some XSD validation in your program before you run it through your code.

The following may help you in your efforts:

- Online XSD Validator Tool:
  http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/
- Xerces for Android: https://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/

Comment: I checked it using http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/ at it is telling some missing definition error.

Comment: Try to simply your code. I'd start by removing the reference to utf-8 and then keep simplying until you get something that works, then build up to what you need. If you need additional resources for learning, I would recommend http://www.w3schools.com/schema/ and http://www.w3schools.com/xml/