# Remove characters not-suitable for UTF-8 encoding from String

Tags: java, mysql, string, encoding, utf-8

I have a text-area on website where user can write anything. Problem happens when user copy paste some text or something which contains non-UTF 8 characters and submit them to server.

Java successfully handles it, as it support UTF-16 but my mySql table support UTF-8 and thus insertion fails.

I was trying to implement some way in business logic itself, to remove any characters which is not suitable for UTF-8 encoding.

Currently I am using this code:

```
new String(java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString).array());
```

But it replaces characters not suitable for UTF-8 with some other obscure characters. Which also does not look good to end user. Could someone please throw some light over any possible solution to tackle this using Java code?

**EDIT :** For example, exception I got while insertion of such values

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A\x0D\x0A...' for column

java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80\xF0\x9F...' for column
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a character that you have a problem with? UTF-8 and UTF-16 are *encodings* for the exact same range of characters, so it should not matter which encoding is supported by your database.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sorry, I don't have that string, user tried to insert but I added the exception I got on insertion of two of such strings

Comment: This problem arises when trying to store emoticons in a MySQL table that uses utf8mb3 or 3-Byte UTF-8 Unicode Encoding. This is the default utf-8 encoding in MySQL 5.x. Its deprecated in MySQL 8, replaced by utf8mb4.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/30074492/4795356 and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UTF-8 is not a character set, it's a character *encoding*, just like UTF-16.

UTF-8 is capable to encode any unicode character and any unicode text to a sequence of bytes, so there is no such thing as characters not suitable for UTF-8.

You're using a constructor of `String` which only takes a byte array ([String(byte[] bytes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-)) which according to the javadocs:

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes **using the platform's default charset**.

It uses the default charset of the platform to interpret the bytes (to convert the bytes to characters). Do not use this. Instead when converting a byte array to `String`, specify the encoding you wish to use explicitly with the [String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-) constructor.

If you have issues with certain characters, that is most likely due to using different character sets or encodings at the server side and at the client side (brownser+HTML). Make sure you use UTF-8 everywhere, do not mix encodings and do not use the default encoding of the platform.

**Some readings how to achieve this:**

[How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for these insights, I am not putting any checks on the client side form submission. If I get you right, then I should use form tag like this `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">` and also on encoding at server side, I should use "UTF-8" instead of leaving it blank and using server's default  ??

Comment: Please read the linked question. It details where and how UTF-8 should be provided, not just the HTML `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the answer with the [CharsetDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869072/) helps. You could change the [CodingErrorAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html) to REPLACE and set a replacement in my example "?". This will output a given replacement string for invalid byte sequences. In this example a [UTF-8 decoder capability and stress test file](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt) is read and decoded:

```java
CharsetDecoder utf8Decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
utf8Decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
utf8Decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
utf8Decoder.replaceWith("?");

// Read stress file
Path path = Paths.get("<path>/UTF-8-test.txt");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
ByteBuffer input = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

// UTF-8 decoding
CharBuffer output = utf8Decoder.decode(input);

// Char buffer to string
String outputString = output.toString();

System.out.println(outputString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will run into this problem when the MySQL column is encoded with old `utf8` using only 3 bytes per character and the value contains a 4-byte character.

The actual solution is to use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` in MySQL.

Otherwise here is my dirty workaround to remove all 4-byte chars:

```
public String removeUtf8Mb4(String text) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, text, true);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String current = st.nextToken();
        if(current.getBytes().length <= 3){
            result.append(current);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are calling `new String` on a `byte[]`. The result of `encode` is a ByteBuffer, and the result of `array` on a ByteBuffer is a `byte[]`.
The constructor `new String(byte[])` will use the platform default encoding for your computer; it can be different on each computer that you run on, so that's not something that you want.
You should at least pass in a character set as the second argument to the String constructor, although I'm not sure which character set you would have in mind.

I'm not sure why you're doing it: if your database uses UTF-8, it will do the encoding for you. You just need to pass un-encoded strings into it.

UTF-8 and UTF-16 can both encode the entire Unicode 6 character set; there are no characters that can be encoded by UTF-16 but not by UTF-8. So that part of your question is unfortunately unanswerable.

For some background:

- http://unicodebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/unicode_encodings.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be useful to you
[Easy way to remove UTF-8 accents from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190656/easy-way-to-remove-utf-8-accents-from-a-string)

Try to use Normalizer as,

```
s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```