# PHP Encoding issues from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding

Ok so I have a Wordpress blog on one page but my front page is not wordpress. I'm pulling a post title and displaying it on the front page like so...

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $entry_new = $row['post_title'];
}
```

But the issue is, when something with quotations comes it up gives the diamond with the question mark. I know it has to be an encoding issue, but if I change the page charset it ISO it breaks the javascript. any ideas?

here's the link... [www.dudnyk.com](http://www.dudnyk.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the special characters (non UTF-8) from the returned strings. Regular expressions would be the way to go; [this will probably help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string)

P.S., those quotes are probably magic quotes, or quotations copied from MSWord.