# Remove non-ASCII characters from string

Tags: php

I'm getting strange characters when pulling data from a website:

```
Â
```

How can I remove anything that isn't a non-extended ASCII character?

---

A more appropriate question can be found here:
*[PHP - replace all non-alphanumeric chars for all languages supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115867/php-replace-all-non-alphanumeric-chars-for-all-languages-supported)*

Comment: What do you mean when you say non-ascii, `Â` is an ascii character (#194)

Comment: oh. well, I mean things like letters and characters such as $(#*@. I don't know how to explain it other than I only want characters you'd be able to type on your keyboard.

Comment: Do you mean non-alphanumeric?

Comment: Could you define what are normal characters?

Comment: I can type "あいうえお" on *my* keyboard... Maybe you just have an *encoding problem* and should interpret the text in the right encoding instead of removing things?

Comment: as an added note, you can run into this on some data as a pair with 194 followed by 160 which is the result of a cut/paste and unicode mangling of the HTML &nbsp;

Comment: @DrewGalbraith #194 is not ASCII, ASCII only goes to #127

Comment: Â is a ***signature*** start of a ***[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) sequence*** (0xC2, octal 302, decimal 194). Another is (0xE2, octal 342, decimal 226). See e.g. code page [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout) or [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout).

Comment: For example, 342 200 234 (octal)   → 0xE2 0x80 0x9C (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201C ([LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)). Most are three bytes, but there is also the very  common 302 240 (octal)   → 0xC2 0xA0 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+00A0 ([NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=156&number=128)).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

A regex replace would be the best option. Using `$str` as an example string and matching it using `:print:`, which is a [POSIX Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html):

```
$str = 'aAÂ';
$str = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $str); // should be aA
```

What `:print:` does is look for all printable characters. The reverse, `:^print:`, looks for all non-printable characters. Any characters that are not part of the current character set will be removed.

**Note:** Before using this method, you must ensure that your current character set is ASCII. POSIX Character Classes support both ASCII and Unicode and will match only according to the current character set. As of PHP 5.6, the default charset is UTF-8.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. :(
I am getting aAÂ.
php 5.3.0. (windows)

Comment: this solution is dependant on the localisation of the perl regex library... in particular it seems to require a broken bersion

Comment: @Jasen They're known as [POSIX Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). They work with any version, but require ASCII to be the selected character set within PHP, since Character Classes also support Unicode fully. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: How do you make ASCII the selected character set via code?

Comment: This is a solution for PHP string variable and not for PHP array variable. **What is the solution for PHP array variable containing these htmlentitycodes &#194 = `Â` which is a-circumflex?**

Comment: @BannedfromSO Take a look at the [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function.

Comment: @ChrisBornhoft - Yes I did this `$a = array_map('trim',$array);`

Comment: Any ideas why this allows any [UTF8 character](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) even when PHP has been setup to use Windows-1252 with `ini_set('default_charset', 'windows-1252');`? I want to get rid of all those Unicode characters and allow only characters from the [Windows-1252 codepage](http://www.kostis.net/charsets/cp1252.htm).

Comment: if you use `[:print:]` some characters may be changed to `?`, see here for more info on a workaround: https://alvinalexander.com/php/how-to-remove-non-printable-characters-in-string-regex

Comment: yes, this answer only works on misconfigured systems 'Â'  is clearly a printing character:(it is both inked, and consumes space) use `'/[[:^ascii:]]/''` instead of `'/[[:^print:]]/'` to strip non-ascii.

Comment: Jasen, your correction was the right solution for me at least.

Comment: @Jasen your answer is the correct one. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work as it made for example from `Anton Dovečer` -> `Anton Doveer` but I'd expect it to do it to `Boris Dovecer`

Comment: @KasparL.Palgi that is *exactly* what the original question asked to accomplish: remove the characters completely. To replace with an non-accented character, you would need to create a custom mapping of the characters you'd like to replace first.

Comment: don't forget to add /u modifier, if you would like to replace non-unicode character with something visible, like question mark (?). So multi-byte characters will be replaced with only one "?" character:

$result = preg_replace('/[[:^ascii:]]/u', '?', $val);

Answer (score 52):

Do you want only [ASCII printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)?

Use this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$str = "abqwrešđčžsff";
$res = preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]/', '', $str);
echo "($str)($res)";
```

Or even better, convert your input to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and use [phputf8 lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phputf8/files/) to translate 'not normal' characters into their ASCII representation:

```
require_once('libs/utf8/utf8.php');
require_once('libs/utf8/utils/bad.php');
require_once('libs/utf8/utils/validation.php');
require_once('libs/utf8_to_ascii/utf8_to_ascii.php');

if(!utf8_is_valid($str))
{
  $str = utf8_bad_strip($str);
}

$str = utf8_to_ascii($str, '');
```

Comment: I also wanted to keep the tab character, so I used this regular expression:
 [^\x00-\x7E]

Comment: Thank you! So much better than the accepted answer! over 10 years later, this saved me a lot of grief!

Answer (score 38):

Use:

```
$clearstring = filter_var($rawstring, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

Note that [`FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` is deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration81.deprecated.php#migration81.deprecated.filter) since PHP 8.1.

Comment: Seems perfect for PHP >= 5.2

Comment: This seems to also strip tags.  For me it was removing <%AnyTextHere%>
See [PHP Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: Heads up: if you [go to functions-online.com to test this](https://ru.functions-online.com/filter_var.html?command={%22variable%22:%22\uf8ff%22,%22filter%22:%22FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING%22,%22options%22:%22FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH%22}), it will put single quotes around `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH` which stops it from working

Comment: This was helpful. Though I used FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH instead of FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH

Comment: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` is deprecated since PHP 8.1

Answer (score 26):

Kind of related: We had a web application that had to send data to a legacy system that could only deal with the first 128 characters of the ASCII character set.

The solution we had to use was something that would "translate" as many characters as possible into close-matching ASCII equivalents, but leave anything that could not be translated alone.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
<?php
// transliterate
if (function_exists('iconv')) {
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    }
?>
```

... but that replaces everything that can't be translated into a question mark (?).

So we ended up doing the following. Check at the end of this function for (commented out) php regex that just strips out non-ASCII characters.

```
<?php
public function cleanNonAsciiCharactersInString($orig_text) {

    $text = $orig_text;

    // Single letters
    $text = preg_replace("/[∂άαáàâãªä]/u",      "a", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[∆лДΛдАÁÀÂÃÄ]/u",     "A", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ЂЪЬБъь]/u",           "b", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[βвВ]/u",            "B", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[çς©с]/u",            "c", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ÇС]/u",              "C", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[δ]/u",             "d", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[éèêëέëèεе℮ёєэЭ]/u", "e", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ÉÈÊË€ξЄ€Е∑]/u",     "E", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[₣]/u",               "F", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[НнЊњ]/u",           "H", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ђћЋ]/u",            "h", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ÍÌÎÏ]/u",           "I", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[íìîïιίϊі]/u",       "i", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[Јј]/u",             "j", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ΚЌК]/u",            'K', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ќк]/u",             'k', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ℓ∟]/u",             'l', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[Мм]/u",             "M", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ñηήηπⁿ]/u",            "n", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[Ñ∏пПИЙийΝЛ]/u",       "N", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[óòôõºöοФσόо]/u", "o", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ÓÒÔÕÖθΩθОΩ]/u",     "O", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ρφрРф]/u",          "p", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[®яЯ]/u",              "R", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ГЃгѓ]/u",              "r", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[Ѕ]/u",              "S", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ѕ]/u",              "s", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[Тт]/u",              "T", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[τ†‡]/u",              "t", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[úùûüџμΰµυϋύ]/u",     "u", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[√]/u",               "v", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ÚÙÛÜЏЦц]/u",         "U", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[Ψψωώẅẃẁщш]/u",      "w", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ẀẄẂШЩ]/u",          "W", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ΧχЖХж]/u",          "x", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ỲΫ¥]/u",           "Y", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ỳγўЎУуч]/u",       "y", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ζ]/u",              "Z", $text);

    // Punctuation
    $text = preg_replace("/[‚‚]/u", ",", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[`‛′’‘]/u", "'", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[″“”«»„]/u", '"', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[—–―−–‾⌐─↔→←]/u", '-', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[  ]/u", ' ', $text);

    $text = str_replace("…", "...", $text);
    $text = str_replace("≠", "!=", $text);
    $text = str_replace("≤", "<=", $text);
    $text = str_replace("≥", ">=", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[‗≈≡]/u", "=", $text);


    // Exciting combinations
    $text = str_replace("ыЫ", "bl", $text);
    $text = str_replace("℅", "c/o", $text);
    $text = str_replace("₧", "Pts", $text);
    $text = str_replace("™", "tm", $text);
    $text = str_replace("№", "No", $text);
    $text = str_replace("Ч", "4", $text);
    $text = str_replace("‰", "%", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[∙•]/u", "*", $text);
    $text = str_replace("‹", "<", $text);
    $text = str_replace("›", ">", $text);
    $text = str_replace("‼", "!!", $text);
    $text = str_replace("⁄", "/", $text);
    $text = str_replace("∕", "/", $text);
    $text = str_replace("⅞", "7/8", $text);
    $text = str_replace("⅝", "5/8", $text);
    $text = str_replace("⅜", "3/8", $text);
    $text = str_replace("⅛", "1/8", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[‰]/u", "%", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[Љљ]/u", "Ab", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[Юю]/u", "IO", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[ﬁﬂ]/u", "fi", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[зЗ]/u", "3", $text);
    $text = str_replace("£", "(pounds)", $text);
    $text = str_replace("₤", "(lira)", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[‰]/u", "%", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[↨↕↓↑│]/u", "|", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[∞∩∫⌂⌠⌡]/u", "", $text);


    //2) Translation CP1252.
    $trans = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    $trans['f'] = '&fnof;';    // Latin Small Letter F With Hook
    $trans['-'] = array(
        '&hellip;',     // Horizontal Ellipsis
        '&tilde;',      // Small Tilde
        '&ndash;'       // Dash
        );
    $trans["+"] = '&dagger;';    // Dagger
    $trans['#'] = '&Dagger;';    // Double Dagger
    $trans['M'] = '&permil;';    // Per Mille Sign
    $trans['S'] = '&Scaron;';    // Latin Capital Letter S With Caron
    $trans['OE'] = '&OElig;';    // Latin Capital Ligature OE
    $trans["'"] = array(
        '&lsquo;',  // Left Single Quotation Mark
        '&rsquo;',  // Right Single Quotation Mark
        '&rsaquo;', // Single Right-Pointing Angle Quotation Mark
        '&sbquo;',  // Single Low-9 Quotation Mark
        '&circ;',   // Modifier Letter Circumflex Accent
        '&lsaquo;'  // Single Left-Pointing Angle Quotation Mark
        );

    $trans['"'] = array(
        '&ldquo;',  // Left Double Quotation Mark
        '&rdquo;',  // Right Double Quotation Mark
        '&bdquo;',  // Double Low-9 Quotation Mark
        );

    $trans['*'] = '&bull;';    // Bullet
    $trans['n'] = '&ndash;';    // En Dash
    $trans['m'] = '&mdash;';    // Em Dash
    $trans['tm'] = '&trade;';    // Trade Mark Sign
    $trans['s'] = '&scaron;';    // Latin Small Letter S With Caron
    $trans['oe'] = '&oelig;';    // Latin Small Ligature OE
    $trans['Y'] = '&Yuml;';    // Latin Capital Letter Y With Diaeresis
    $trans['euro'] = '&euro;';    // euro currency symbol
    ksort($trans);

    foreach ($trans as $k => $v) {
        $text = str_replace($v, $k, $text);
    }

    // 3) remove <p>, <br/> ...
    $text = strip_tags($text);

    // 4) &amp; => & &quot; => '
    $text = html_entity_decode($text);


    // transliterate
    // if (function_exists('iconv')) {
    // $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    // }

    // remove non ascii characters
    // $text =  preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $text);

    return $text;
}

?>
```

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#74101 , that should only be an issue if you do not select a proper locale (other than C or POSIX)

Comment: there are only 128 characters in the ascii character set.

Comment: Re *"the first 128 characters of the ASCII character set"*: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only has 128: *"ASCII has just 128 code points"*. The last bit is used for extensions, like code page [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Comment: iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT' makes the whole string blank if any of characters was non-ASCII. It removes even good ASCII characters.

Answer (score 4):

I also think that the best solution might be to use a regular expression.

Here's my suggestion:

```
function convert_to_normal_text($text) {

    $normal_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9\s`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>?,.\/\"\'\\\[\]";
    $normal_text = preg_replace("/[^$normal_characters]/", '', $text);

    return $normal_text;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$before = 'Some "normal characters": Abc123!+, some ASCII characters: ABC+ŤĎ and some non-ASCII characters: Ąąśćł.';
$after = convert_to_normal_text($before);
echo $after;
```

Displays:

```
Some "normal characters": Abc123!+, some ASCII characters: ABC+ and some non-ASCII characters: .
```

Comment: FYI, Typo on line 4:  '$normal_caracters' => '$normal_characters'

Answer (score 1):

I just had to add the header

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: that will fix the case where UTF8 is being interpreted as WIN-1252 which is the default encoding for HTML, however it will not remove any characters from a string.

Comment: They probably don't have control over the website: *"I'm getting strange characters when pulling data from a website:"*

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward and there isn't any need for an [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) function:

```
// Remove all characters that are not the separator, a-z, 0-9, or whitespace
$string = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote('-').'a-z0-_9\s]+!', '', strtolower($string));

// Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
$string = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote('-').'\s]+!u', '-', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved

```
$text = 'Châu Thái  Nhân 12/09/2022';
echo preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $text);
//Châu Thái  Nhân 12/09/2022
```

Comment: What is the result? What does it do? Completely wipes out the characters? Removes non-printable characters? Please explain your solution. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73686605/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***without*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to do something like this is by using [ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) command. This way you will be able to keep characters written in any language. Just remember to first test your text's ord results. This will not work on Unicode.

```
$name = "βγδεζηΘKgfgebhjrf!@#$%^&";
// This function will clear all non greek and english characters on greek-iso charset
function replace_characters($string)
{
    $str_length = strlen($string);
    for ($x=0; $x < $str_length; $x++)
    {
        $character = $string[$x];
        if ((ord($character)  >  64 && ord($character) <   91) ||
            (ord($character)  >  96 && ord($character) <  123) ||
            (ord($character)  > 192 && ord($character) <  210) ||
            (ord($character)  > 210 && ord($character) <  218) ||
            (ord($character)  > 219 && ord($character) <  250) ||
             ord($character) == 252 || ord($character) == 254)
        {
            $new_string = $new_string.$character;
        }
    }
    return $new_string;
}
// End function

$name = replace_characters($name);

echo $name;
```

Comment: Heavy-handed but tweakable... I like it.

Comment: You're doing ord() on the same character over and over again just for different comparisons (line 9). That's extremely inefficient. You should save result of ord() in variable and then reuse it in conditional. Also, consider using === instead of == as use of == is discouraged. Although I don't blame you for this, ironically PHP manual for ord() shows using == in examples.