# PHP - replace all non-alphanumeric chars for all languages supported

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, multibyte

Hi  i'm actually trying replacing all the NON-alphanumeric chars from a string like this:

```
mb_ereg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]+/i','-',$string);
```

first problem is it doesn't replaces chars like `"."` from the string.

Second i would like to add multybite support for all users languages to this method.

How can i do that?

Any help appriciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Just add the period to your character list. ^a-z0-9\s. ---As for "adding multibyte support", if you mean replacing accents and such, I know no other method than making a huge array with things like é => e, and use it for strtr.

Comment: @Ariane it's ok so? i mean i already got period !? no doesn't matter for accented ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9\s]+/u', '-', $string);
```

When the `u` flag is used on a regular expression, `\p{L}` (and `\p{Letter}`) matches any character in any of the Unicode letter categories.

Comment: omg dude i used mb_ereg_replace() sorry i updated question @F.J

Comment: should i use preg_replace() instead? :P

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about `mb_ereg_replace()`, but `preg_replace()` should work so switching is definitely an option.

Answer (score 1):

It should replace `.` with `-`, you're probably mixing up your data in the first place.

As for the multi-byte support, add the `u` modifier and look into [PCRE properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), namely `\p{Letter}`:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~[^0-9\p{Letter}]+~iu', '-', $string);
```

Comment: omg dude i used mb_ereg_replace() sorry i updated question @Alix Axel

Comment: @badbetonbreakbutbedbackbone: Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (`preg`) are more powerful than Extended Regular Expressions (`ereg`).

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way is:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\P{Xan}++~u', '-', $string);
```

`\p{Xan}` contains numbers and letters in all languages, thus `\P{Xan}` contains all that is not a letter or a number.

Comment: thanks but what about mb_ereg_replace() is it not better? can you tell me if i need to switch to preg_replace() and why does? :P

Comment: @badbetonbreakbutbedbackbone: No. The u modifier at the end make that the pattern can deal with unicode with preg_* functions. IMHO, the mb_ereg functions will disappear. preg_* functions are faster and support unicode.

Answer (score 0):

This expression does replace dots. For multibyte use `u` modifier (UTF-8).

Comment: omg dude i used mb_ereg_replace() sorry i updated question @Ziarno