# What is the encoding of an HTTP request?

Tags: http

When doing something like `json_encode($_SERVER)` I get an error because the input to be JSON-encoded is not valid UTF-8.  In fact, I looked into this error and noticed some user agent strings were encoded in ISO-8859-1.  How do I know what encoding was used for the HTTP request, so that I can use `utf8_encode()` or `iconv()` as appropriate to be able to JSON-encode the data?

Comment: HTTP Headers like `User-Agent` should be ASCII. The HTTP request and response body are encoded using the text encoding specified in the `charset` attribute of the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Thank you @EricLaw. So if it's not ASCII it means the browser simply sent a bad request?  In my case the user agent contains "OrangeEspaña" for instance.

Comment: Any header not using ASCII is foolish. Having said that, historically, RFC2616 allowed field content in the ASCII superset `ISO-8859-1`. Any other character set is supposed to be escaped using the scheme of RFC2231 (not commonly supported). Some clients will use UTF-8 or %-escaped UTF-8 in headers; the latter is preferable in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the standard doesn't say: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

A request *body* should have an encoding in a Content-Type header, but header values should be plain ascii. Anything beyond that isn't specified from what I can tell. I'm not sure that it is strictly *wrong* but there's apparently no standard you can use for a call to iconv.

What I would do is just loop through the string and remove any non-ASCII value. Maybe you could hack it out with a simple str_replace call or preg_replace [remove non-ascii characters from string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781911/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-string-in-php) .

Comment: The answer is correct, however RFC 2616 is irrelevant nowadays.