# Why is ASCII representation of this character returns as 226 128 153?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, char, ascii

So I am playing with this tool:

http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/

When I try this character:

```
'
```

I see the value **039** which can be verified from: http://www.asciitable.com

But I am curios about:

```
’
```

This character in the same tool will return: **226 128 153**

But as far as I know ASCII is 8 bits (or even 7...)

What is **226 128 153** in here?

Comment: The character in question is not an ASCII character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that that is the UTF16 representation. probably that website is converting the characters to their code representation with `"’".charCodeAt(0);` in Javascript

Answer (score 6):

The character you have is [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), which is also the typographically correct way of representing the apostrophe in most positions.

What the site does, is representing the characters in UTF-8. As you can see in the page I linked, this character is encoded as three bytes, `0xE2 0x80 0x99` in hexadecimal, or **226 128 153** in decimal.

The reason that that page uses UTF-8 instead of ASCII? Simple. First, ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Second, UTF-8 supports the entire Unicode. So there's rarely a reason to use ASCII if UTF-8 can be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have this same issue (trying to actually convert a string to uppercase, ran into this character and it 'broke' a bunch of methods of converting a string with special characters to uppercase.

I used this solution:

```
    $text = preg_replace("/[`‛′’‘]/u", "'", $text);
```

(NOT MINE - taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925209/6136613)

This then converts it to a regular comma, and you can perform normal php functions on it.

Answer (score 1):

The first character is ASCII, code 39. The second is UNICODE character, code 8217.

See [UNICODE character table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character), specifically for [this character](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=8217).

For more information read the [UNICODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) article.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#res').html("’".charCodeAt(0));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='res'><div>
```