# MySql regexp escaping apostrophe(’)

Tags: mysql, regex, escaping

I can't find a proper way to escape apostrophe sign(’) in my mysql query. Regexp I have, works fine with online tools for regexp testing.

Problematic **example** is the string `G’Schlössl`.

I want to have **optional apostrophe sign in the query in front of the `s`** character `G(’?)Schlö(’?)ssl` for all the different cases which could occur in other strings. I am not sure if the problem is caused by incorrect sign escaping but I have tried many options like `’?`, `\’?`, `\’{0,1}` which works for the first occurrence but doesn't for the second optional one and **cause query to return nothing**. Other possibilities like `’’?`, `[’]?`, `[\’]?`, `[\’]{0,1}` does not work even for the first one.

```
select id, name from restaurant where name regexp '.*g\’?(s|ß|ss|sz)chl(o|ö|oe)\’?s.*';
```

When I remove the last `\’?` it works:

```
select id, name from restaurant where name regexp '.*g\’?(s|ß|ss|sz)chl(o|ö|oe)s.*';
```

When I replace the last `\’?` with `x?` it works as well:

```
select id, name from restaurant where name regexp '.*g\’?(s|ß|ss|sz)chl(o|ö|oe)x?s.*';
```

Any ideas where the problem is or what else to try?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql) explains escaping normal single quote only, which seems not to work in my case.

Comment: If your first `\’` works, so should do the second one at the end. What do you want to match with this pattern?

Comment: Have you tried using [[.apostrophe.]]?

Comment: @YasenZhelev yea i think it should work and I have no idea why it doesn't in mysql and does in js. I want a query for the cases like Jimmy's and someone typing just jimmys to a search. Idea was to include ’? in front of s char.

Comment: @PaulF yea, doesn't work even for the first one. But I wonder why even [’]? does not work as well.

Comment: Have a look at these two links :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286059/why-is-ascii-representation-of-this-character-returns-as-226-128-153 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067566/unicode-in-mysql-regex - first shows the "apostrophe" is actually a Unicode character, second shows REGEX doesn't work well with Unicode.

Comment: First, check what's in the database exactly, is it a `'` or a `’`, if it's a `'` then `''?` will work, if it's a `’` then `’?` will work, if it's a `’` and `’?` does not work then you have a mismatch between the encoding in your database and the encoding in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `\’?`, try `(’)?`.  I'm thinking that the `?` may apply to only the last byte of `’`.  By using parentheses instead, the `?` applies to the entire 3 bytes (hex `E28099`) of the "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK".