# PHP decode ANSI characters

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc, decode

How can I find and replace such characters as ˇ in a string? When I copied these to a simple str_replace method, was not any effect. It comes from an MS Access Database by PDO and ODBC.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to replace it with?

Also note that if you're trying to replace multiple characters at once, [you need to pass in an array of these characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

For example, if you're trying to simply remove these characters via `str_replace`, the following would work:

```
$test = "├ę ├│ tester";
$result = str_replace(["├ę", "├│"], "", $test);
print_r($result);
```

Results in : 
`tester`

If you're trying to strip out any non-standard characters, [look into using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781911/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-string-in-php).