# How to remove unknown character in a text file?

Tags: php

I have a text file containing this; "I do not know" character. Already search on google but I'm having hard time getting desired search result since I do not know what is the general term for this kind of character.

[image]

I tried removing it using below code but nothing happens. I also tried "\f" because I thought that character is form feed but still can't remove.

```
$replace = str_replace("\0", ' ', $str);
```

**EDIT:**

The said character is really form feed but somehow below code is not working for me.

```
$replace = str_replace("\f", ' ', $str);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781911/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-string-in-php

Comment: @HankyPanky thank you very much. I also do not need to remove ñ

Comment: @HankyPanky can you explain why you downvoted?

Comment: I didn't. What makes it appear such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why, but using `str_replace` is not working to remove the 'FF' (Form Feed) character

```
$replace = str_replace("\f", ' ', $str); // not working
```

Using below code solves my problem but kinda not look good because it is using regex to replace a single character only. Still, this works:

```
$replace = preg_replace('/[\f]/', " ", $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use prep_replace command to perform a regular expression search and replace.

```
$replace = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9 _\-\+\&]/', '',$str);
```

Note: You need to decide the first parameter to the preg_replace function call for the set of unwanted characters you don't want. You might be interested to remove non printable characters.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. I also tried this but the 'NUL' character and 'FF' still showing when I use this. I'll try other regex pattern and thank you again

Answer (score -1):

Seems like an issue with your header. Try once after adding this on you header.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Sir for helping me out but this is not the answer I'm looking for. :)