# Format input string from unwanted characters

Tags: php

Hi how to format a string from unwanted characters in php? Tried strip_tags, mysqli_real_escape_string, but no success.

This is the scenario. The string is entered through an android app it allows rich text inputs, below is the image
[image]

When added the db entry looks normal, below is the image

[image]

Now at last the string is read from a url, below is the image

[image]

As you can see there's Â character between the bold text, but it's not appearing in the db entry on second image. Actually this string is read by a gsm module and it's causing the system to break due to the Â character.

strip_tags returns the same string, whereas mysqli_real_escape_string returns empty string.

How to clean such strings from unwanted characters(not just Â) in php to return only the plain text?

Comment: Can you show what that string looks like in your PHP code? Like the var_dump output of $_GET or $_POST or wherever it ends up?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with Unicode vs. ASCII. your locale must be set to ASCII before the code will work since the [[:^print:]] reference determines what is not printable based on the current locale.
This is the post that has the answer for both strings and arrays:

[Remove non-ascii characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781911/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-string)

```
$str = 'aAÂ';
$str = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $str); // should be aA
```

And another reference with a good explanation:
https://alvinalexander.com/php/how-to-remove-non-printable-characters-in-string-regex