# Regex to remove non alphanumeric characters from UTF8 strings

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove characters, like punctuation, commas, dashes etc from a string, in a multibyte safe manner?

I will be working with input from many different languages and I am wondering if there is something that can help me with this

Thanks

Comment: You want to keep only `a-z` and `0-9`? Or are all the special characters from different languages aswell?

Comment: explaining why my result in a better approach being suggested.

Comment: @Marcus. I need to keep the unicode characters

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are the unicode character class thingys that you can use:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

To match any non-letter symbols you can just use `\PL+`, the negation of `\p{L}`. To not remove spaces, use a charclass like `[^\pL\s]+`. Or really just remove punctuation with `\pP+`

Well, and obviously don't forget the regex `/u` modifier.

Comment: I think this one has potential. I need to investigate. Thanks mario

Comment: to match space character (code point) use  \pZ  instead of \s

Comment: This does not handle the non-numeric part. Correct answer should be `[^\pL^\pN\s]+`

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
$clean = preg_replace( "/[^\p{L}|\p{N}]+/u", " ", $raw );
$clean = preg_replace( "/[\p{Z}]{2,}/u", " ", $clean );
```

Comment: Can you perhaps describe what exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Similar post

[Remove non-utf8 characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string)

I'm not sure if this covers all characters though.

According to this post on th dreamincode forum

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78179-regular-expression-to-remove-non-ascii-characters/

this should work

```
/[^\x{21}-\x{7E}\s\t\n\r]/
```

Comment: I think this works only for ASCII, and the writer clearly mentiones UTF8 strings.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will be usefull?

```
$newstring = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/', $oldstring);
```

Comment: This will remove non ASCII characters as well. I don't want this