# bad chars in a UTF-8 file

Tags: scripting, utf-8

I have a file that geany tells me is a UTF-8 file but with characters like:

Ã¹ instead of ù

and so on. That's because 0xC3 + 0xB9 are considered two characters instead of just U+00F9, right?
With geany the encoding of the file is already UTF-8, if I switch to ISO-8859 of course I don't get corrected characters.

Is there like a bash command, java class, ruby module or a magic potion that can automatically change this thing without the need to do this by hand?

EDIT:

If i try to switch I can't save the file because I have errors like:

> Error message: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input The error
>   occurred at "€" (line: 1389, column: 46).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Geany is interpreting the file as ISO-8859-1 which, as you say, means it's displaying two characters instead of one.

Two commands that might be helpful: `od` and `iconv`. od is "octal dump" which you can use to verify exactly what bytes are in the file. [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) is for converting strings from one encoding to another.

Comment: actually geanie sees it as utf-8. If I lunch file command on the file I get UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines

Comment: That's strange. I don't suppose you can host the file somewhere so I can try it in Geany myself?

Comment: I can't because it contains sensible data.

Comment: If I try to convert it to ISO-8859-1 I got this message: Error message: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input
The error occurred at "€" (line: 1389, column: 46).

Comment: So you see, we have an UTF-8 but with chars with accent in their two-chars-ISO-8859 form. It's freaking weird.

Comment: Ah, okay, that looks like a different character. It could be that someone's managed to get a mix of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 in there.

Comment: Exactly. The problem is that I can't see how I can correct this problem creating a script instead of a doing it by hand.

Comment: Depending on the size of the file, doing it by hand might be quicker. Keep running iconv and correct each character you come across. Apart from that, a script which iterates over the file interpreting bytes and handling any ones it doesn't like ("Not a UTF-8 byte stream? Try again as Latin-1 and then convert to UTF-8") is the first idea off the top of my head.

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string You could modify that so that when it hits a single byte it doesn't like, it re-interprets the byte as latin-1, converts *that* to UTF-8 and puts it back in the string. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like bug of Geany. 
If you open **ANSI** file (which is created in Windows), Geany is interpreting the file as **ISO-8859-1**. 
When you are trying to add some unicode symbols and save it, you get

```
An error occurred while converting the file from UTF-8 in "ISO-8859-1".
```

Try **Document->Set Encoding->Unicode (UTF-8)** and save document. It helps.