# Remove special non standard character from string

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I have this string `”Good morning, Dave”`. This string contains two non standard double quotes.

Whenever I try to insert into my database  table it is converted  to this string `%u201DGoodmorning,Dave%u201D`

I try to replace this kind of character using `preg_replace` but they are not helpful.This is what I have tried

```
1) preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $String);
2) preg_replace('#[^\w()/.%\-&]#',"",$string);
```

I also Try `mysql_real_escape_string`, but is is also not helpful. How can I do this?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
urldecode($string);
```

instead of using the string on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried str_replace?  format is (item to replace, replace with, string the item is found in.

Comment: there are lots of this kind of character are present in any string. How can I map this in str_replace?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were nearly there. 0x201D is the unicode character  "RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK"

See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm

So you could try...

```
preg_replace('/\\X201d/', '', $String);
```