# PHP - How to replace ï¿½ in a string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string that contains a character ï¿½ I haven't been able to replace it correctly.

> str_replace("ï¿½", "", $myvar);

doesn't work, does anyone know how to remove/replace the ï¿½ in the string??

Or is there easy way to do this in MYSQL level with character encoding ?

Comment: Is there an encoding problem here? Is it just me or that's three characters (ï, inverted ? and 1/2 character)?

Comment: i think it suppose to appear as a "\"" its encoding problem, it shows as above "ï¿½ even the html is set to utf-8

Comment: ˙ǝɯ oʇ ǝuıɟ sʞooן buıɥʇʎɹǝʌǝ 'ou

Comment: I believe you might have a mis-match of encodings somewhere. What I remember of PHP is that it's a minefield, with no simple way to go Unicode, but please check where there was a mis-match. For example, PHP strings are not Unicode. Look at your database in some admin tool, maybe it's even stored wrong.

Comment: maybe its becos i used iso-88.. first then after a while i used utf-8 so part of my db is iso and i have problem in somehow making them to utf. but i dont see any easy solutions here.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `mb_ereg_replace` for multibyte char replacement

```
string mb_ereg_replace ( string $pattern , string $replacement , string $string [, string $option = "msr" ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use this funcion: https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8 in order to clear all your non UTF-8 characters. It should help you with the above characters too.

PS. There are some other method described on [Remove non-utf8 characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string)