# PHP Clean Odd Characters from String

Tags: php, string, str-replace, resource-cleanup

I'm receiving some information using sockets
But it gets some garbage depending the client and the OS.

Example : Receiving "Hello" string

```
ÿþ^Xÿþ^_ÿþ ÿþ!ÿþ"ÿþ'ÿü^Eÿþ#Hello
```

That gets stored in a $msg variable. How can i clean it up from those strange characters?.
(The characters varies from msg to msg).

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string this may help you

Comment: You can use `preg_replace('/[^\w\d]+/', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($str)))` to get just letters and numbers.

Comment: I just used preg_replace('/[^\w\d\s]+/', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($str))) and did the trick. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it worked

```
preg_replace('/[^\w\d\s]+/', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($str)));
```