# Remove unwanted characters

Tags: php

I have a problem to displaying text. How to remove � this character from string.

I am getting the follow,

> It�s back to the beginning for Tom Clancy�s CIA operative in this
>   prequel/origin story. It�s back to the beginning for Tom Clancy�s CIA
>   operative in this prequel/origin story.

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string

Comment: This must be html entity. Which entity you are using in your code ?

Comment: Thank for quick reply. I am using htmlspecialchars($string)

Comment: Be sure u use the correct encoding for your database, html files, database connection and charset meta tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code

```
$str = 'It�s back to the beginning for Tom Clancy�s CIA operative in this prequel/origin story. It�s back to the beginning for Tom Clancy�s CIA operative in this prequel/origin story.';
$str = filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
echo $str ;
```

Comment: Thank you Anju Raghunath. Its working

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter_var` function you can remove the unwanted character.It Filters a variable with a specified filter

```
$str = 'your string'


$str = filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

echo $str;
```

It Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails.

Documentation is found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php