# PHP remove all non UTF-8 characters from string

Tags: php, string, utf-8, preg-replace

I need to remove symbols like ",./! and so on from the beginning and the end of the string. but still need to leave numbers and characters like ąčęėįšųž and many more from UTF-8.
for example:

1. the result of string `&g&g` should be `g&g`;
2. the result of string `ąčęėį` should be `ąčęėį`;
3. the result of string `"name"` should be `name`;
4. the result of string `69` should be `69`
5. the result of string `--abc---` should be `abc`

I believe it should be done using `preg_replace` but can't find how.

Comment: [In this post, indicates how solve your problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well, this will do what you want:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?:^[^\p{L}\p{N}]+|[^\p{L}\p{N}]+$)/u', '', $input);
```

Where

`\p{L}` stands for any character that is a letter (unicode)
`\p{N}` stands for any character that is a digit (unicode)
`[^\p{L}\p{N}]` is a negative character class that matches characters that is not letter or digit.

Comment: well exactly this code removes all characters. because \P{L} removes all non letter characters and \P{N} all non numbers there is nothing left.