# PHP file_get_contents Maximum execution time exceeded (Cause of emotes?)

Tags: php, json, api, file-get-contents, steam

I started messing around with the Steam API a bit ago, and I made a simple site showing profile information using the GetPlayerSummaries method. It's been working great, right until some of my friends started adding iOS emotes in their name, which causes the following:

> **Fatal error**: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in *file* on line 137

This is what's on that line in the file:

```
public function getPlayerSummary($steamid) {
    $contents = file_get_contents( "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".SteamAPI_APIKey."&steamids=".$steamid );
    $json = json_decode($contents, true);

    foreach($json['response']['players'] as $key => $value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

(This is in a function, $steamid is defined when calling the function)

This should return (JSON):

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "_removed_",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "_removed_ ",
            "lastlogoff": 1426734965,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/_removed_/",
            "avatar": "_removed_",
            "avatarmedium": "_removed_",
            "avatarfull": "_removed_",
            "personastate": 0,
            "realname": "_removed_",
            "primaryclanid": "_removed_",
            "timecreated": 1349251405,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "DE"
        }
    ]

}
```

}

But the "" in the personaname messes it up, as it works for everyone else without it :/ This is a ghost emote, same happens with another friend using a monkey emote in his name.

Would anyone have any idea how I could resolve this?

Comment: Please post more of the code, I don't think that `file_get_contents` is causing this (PHP is not very good at reporting errors), my guess would be that `json_decode` can't parse strange characters, you could [replace not utf-8 chars in content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string) and then `json_decode` string

Comment: Added a bit more, though having nothing but the `file_get_contents` in the function still causes it :/

Comment: What happens if you try to read file char by char?
http://pastebin.com/Qr7RxvHW

Comment: That works! Setting the charset to UTF-8, it turns the emote into a square (and into the actual emote on my phone) - Should I use this, and then `json_decode` or would that be a bad idea?

Comment: What about: http://pastebin.com/9FTEsjYY reading file char by char is not very good idea :)

Comment: Works as well, same result :) EDIT: Something is acting up ... using `file_get_contents` also works when it's in a file on its own :/ Uhm

Comment: Dont put it into file, read form URL :)

Comment: Have a look: http://pastebin.com/FtQetQ2E - Btw you think we can find somewhere else to chat? (I don't have enough repo to chat on here :P) EDIT: IM AN IDIOT, I HAD TO USE `PRINT_R` .... then it works fine, derp. But yet still not in my function

Comment: google hangout b.kustan@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

put following line at the top of php file,

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that'll help my case? That'll cause the page to never load, haha

Comment: you can do this in php.ini

Comment: Yeah I know, but how is that going to help? :/ I did it, and it just never loads

Answer (score 0):

Note:

If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php