# How to upload then read JSON file in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am planning to upload a JSON file and then read it using laravel. I think it is possible but my code is  not working

this is my code:

```
$json_file = $request->json_file;   
$json_file->move("uploads/json",$json_file->getClientOriginalName());
$json_data = file_get_contents(env('APP_URL', '')."/uploads/json/".$json_file->getClientOriginalName());
echo $json_data;
$json_data = json_decode($json_data);
var_dump($json_data);
```

when I upload the json file I always getting `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`. I have no idea about it since my json file contains

```
{
    "prefix": "#",
    "token": "46881dfsf",
    "as_link": "http://mylink.com"
}
```

any idea about  my case?

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139747/php-file-get-contents-maximum-execution-time-exceeded-cause-of-emotes

Comment: if you dd $json_file after first line, can you see any results?

Comment: `echo $json_data;` this might be throwing the `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`