# PHP function for removing all invalid characters

Tags: php

I've been trying and searching for a working solution, but nothing seemed to work..

I'm making a social website, where the users can post. I would like to check the text before it goes into the database.

I would like to make the regular characters enabled (a-zA-Z0-9) + some utf8 characters (áÁéÉíÍóÓöÖőŐúÚüÜűŰ) and some other characters (.,?!;. etc.)

I've been trying, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9áÁéÉíÍóÓöÖőŐúÚüÜűŰ \.\,\?\!\:\;\-\+\<\>\%\~\€\$\[\]\{\}\@\&\#\*\"\„\”\/]/', '', $string);
```

Could someone help me out?

Is there anything easier? The reason why I'm doing this is because I don't wanna allow the users to spam the database with illegal characters, or HTML tags.. It would be so bad if someone wrote a post like this `"blabla</div>".`

Comment: What's an *"illegal character"*? And why not just use utf-8 but apply `strip_tags()`?

Comment: Maybe Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string

Comment: You say you don't want users to submit HTML tags, but all of the characters necessary to write them are white-listed in your regex.

Comment: That `preg_replace` call also looks like it works fine - what actual problems are you having? See https://eval.in/631655

Comment: ..."_It would be so bad if someone wrote a post like this "blabla"._"... what does that mean?

Comment: Try using htmlentities($yourstring, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: @MagnusEriksson "blablabla" is a brazilian expression

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe - So what does it mean in this context? :o

Comment: If you aren't using markdown or bbcode for your site, you should probably look into [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a textarea or input value to record the User entries, you could use a str_replace() function to search through the string of characters to replace the illegal characters.  Link to str_replace in php manual:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Code example:

```
    <?php
      $userInput = "Tex.t tha!t wil;l be te>sted that is inp?uted b;y user";
      //Following Array is all characters you deem unwanted
      $illegalChar = array(".", ",", "?", "!", ":", ";", "-", "+", "<", ">", "%", "~", "€", "$", "[", "]", "{", "}", "@", "&", "#", "*", "„");
      $charString = str_replace($illegalChar, "", $userInput);
      echo $charString;
      //Output is "Text that will be tested that is inputed by user"
    ?>
```

Comment: You basically make an array of unwanted chars, and then use the str_replace function to erase them. if you wish to check an html form that is involved with a textarea or input value, make $userInput = <name of html field>