# preg_match does not find a UTF-8 character at the beginning of a binary string which contain non-UTF8 characters

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-match

If is somewhere in the string a non-UTF8 character, preg_match with the modifier u returns false for an error.
For example:

```
<?php
$string = "ABCD\xc3";
$r = preg_match('/^./u',$string, $match);
var_dump($r);  //bool(false)
```

This example for try yourself: https://3v4l.org/qkHl4

The regular expression finds the first character if the non-UTF8 character is removed at the end.

```
$string = "ABCD";
$r = preg_match('/^./u',$string, $match);
var_dump($r, $match); 
//int(1) array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" }
```

Is there an easy way to use regular expressions to identify a UTF-8 character at the beginning for strings that also contain non-UTF8 characters?

Comment: I had also expected for the first example that the character "A" is found. I suspect preg_match first checks the whole string if all characters are UTF-8 before using the regular expression.

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215387/3278362) you can remove invalid utf characters using [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: See this: https://3v4l.org/iYiah

Comment: If your string is not valid UTF-8, why use `u` mode and expect it to work…?

Comment: This "\u{c3}" is a UTF-8 character "Ã" and this "\xc3" is not a UTF-8 character. I have strings which contains also NON-UTF8 chars.

Comment: If your string contains "non-UTF-8 characters", then it's not a valid UTF-8/Unicode string, and `u` expects and only works on UTF-8 strings. You either have a valid UTF-8 string and can then use Unicode regexen on it, or you don't and you can't.

Comment: mb_substr() with encoding UTF-8 can handle invalid UTF-8 strings. This behavior is unfortunately not documented. That's why I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think after a long search I found an answer myself.

The modifier u works only if the entire string is a valid UTF-8 string. 
Even if only the first character is to be found, the entire string is checked first.
The modifier u can not be used for this problem. However, regular expressions can be used.

```
function utf8Char($string){
    $ok = preg_match(
      '/^[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]
      |^[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]
      |^[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]
      |^[\x00-\x7f]/sx',
      $string,
      $match);
    return $ok ? $match[0] : false;      
}


var_dump(utf8char("€a\xc3def"));  //string(3) "€"
var_dump(utf8char("a\xc3def"));  //string(1) "a"
var_dump(utf8char("\xc3def"));  //bool(false)
```

The non-UTF8-bytes can be retrieved using the substr function.

```
var_dump(substr("\xc3def",0,1)); //string(1) "�"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215387/3278362) you can remove invalid utf characters using [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
$string = "ABCD\xc3";
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$r = preg_match('/^./u', $string, $match);
var_dump($r, $match);
```

give the following result:

```
int(1)
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "A"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, does not help me. The line with mb_convert_encoding replaces all non-UTF8 with "?". So I can not say if the first character is a valid UTF-8 or not.
Note: To parse a escaped character in hexadecimal notation how "\xc3" the string must enclosed in double-quotes (").

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com), which handles UTF8 errors in a more cooperative way:

```
try {
    pattern('^.', 'u')->match("ABCD\xc3")->all();
catch (SafeRegexException $e) {
    // handle
}
```