# Hash url transform to a long url htaccess? php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have constructed my entire webpage with hashes (`http://example.com/videos#video01`), but the problem is when I want to share on facebook obviously it doesn't recognize the hash, so my question is: Is there a way to transform or redirect the hash url to a long social-friendly-url?

**Solution:**
I tried one more time with bit.ly's API, I got 50 videos to show each with a hash at the end of the url. I made a little cache script (bit.ly has a limit) and I wrote with PHP a "foreach", seem like bit.ly accepts hashes.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: By the way, I tried with bit.ly's API and didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The # and everything after is not sent to a server. In your case you're only sending `http://example.com/videos`.

Comment: I know, so is there way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

New Link format: `http://example.com/videos?name=video01`

Call this function toward top of controller or `http://example.com/videos/index.php`:

```
function redirect()
{
    if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
        // sanitize & validate $_GET['name']
        // Remove anything which isn't a word, whitespace, number
        // or any of the following caracters -_~,;[]().
        // If you don't need to handle multi-byte characters
        // you can use preg_replace rather than mb_ereg_replace
        $file = mb_ereg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;\[\]\(\).])", '', $_GET['name']);
        // Remove any runs of periods
        $file = mb_ereg_replace("([\.]{2,})", '', $file);
        $valid = file_exists('pathToFiles/' . $file);
        if ($valid) {
            $url = '/videos#' . $file;
        } else {
            $url = '/your404page.php';
        }
        header("Location: $url");
    }
}
```

Sanitization snippet from this highly ranked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021729/1296209