# how to add number in picture when upload if same file name of picture

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have this code for upload

```
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photo/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

$location="photo/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

then the insert `$location` code for sql to add

The Question is how to have my picture file name number add ex: if i have "Picture.jpg "uploaded if i will upload again and same file name the output of the filename will be  *Picture(1).jpg* and if I upload again with the same file name the output filename will be *Picture(2).jpg* and so on I want the  "()" to increment if ever i will upload same file name. thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achived with loop:

```php
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
$i = 0;
do {
    $image_name = $info['filename'] . ($i ? "_($i)" : "") . "." . $info['extension'];
    $i++;
    $path = "photo/" . $image_name;
} while(file_exists($path));

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path);
```

You should also sanitize input file name:

- [string sanitizer for filename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2021624/67332)
- [Sanitizing strings to make them URL and filename safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2668854/67332)

Comment: thank you...  ^^ this work for me, I will also check string sanitizer

Answer (score 1):

This code is untested, but I would think something along the lines of:

```
if (file_exists('path/to/file/image.jpg')){
 $i = 1;
 while (file_exists('path/to/file/image ('.$i.').jpg')){
   $i++;
 }
 $name = 'image ('.$i.');
}
```

And then save the image to $name.  (which at some point will result in image (2).jpg)

Comment: Wow answer. I was thinking to go for recursive function and what not, this is simple logic. 10 years old answer does the trick for me :).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a unique image name after upload even if they have same name or they are uploading in loop means multiple upload.

```
$time = time() + sprintf("%06d",(microtime(true) - floor(microtime(true))) * 1000000);

$new_name=$image_name.'_'.$time.'.'.$extension
```

You can add the image name with a unique time stamp which differ each nano seconds and generate unique time stamp

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$path = "photo/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$ext = pathinfo ($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
$name = pathinfo ( $path, PATHINFO_FILENAME ] );

for($i = 0; file_exists($path); $i++){
if($i > 0){
  $path =  "photo/" .$name.'('.$id.').'.$ext;
} 
}

echo $path;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$pathinfo = pathinfo($name);
$FileName = $pathinfo['filename'];
$ext = $pathinfo['extension'];
$actual_image_name = $FileName.time().".".$ext; 
 $location="photo/".$converted_name;    
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $location))
{


}
```