# Encoding problem with /usr/lib64/python3.4/http/client.py

Tags: python

I do not understand the error below. If I run :
python3.4 ./bug.py "salé.txt"
It is fine.

If I run : python3.4 ./bug.py "Capture d’écran du 2019-03-21 15-17-10.png"
I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bug.py", line 45, in <module>
    status=testB_CreateSimpleDocumentWithFile(session)
  File "./bug.py", line 32, in testB_CreateSimpleDocumentWithFile
    status, result = session.create_document_with_properties(path,mydoc,simple_document,properties=props,files=kk)
  File "/home/karim/testatrium/nuxeolib/session.py", line 345, in create_document_with_properties
    _document_properties, _ = self.encode_properties(properties, files)
  File "/home/karim/testatrium/nuxeolib/session.py", line 251, in encode_properties
    _names, _sizes = self.upload_files(files, batch_id=_batch_id)
  File "/home/karim/testatrium/nuxeolib/session.py", line 136, in upload_files
    _status, _result = self.execute_api(param=_param, headers=_headers, file_name=_name)
  File "/home/karim/testatrium/nuxeolib/session.py", line 1325, in execute_api
    _connection.request(method, url, headers=h2, body=data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1139, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1179, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1110, in putheader
    values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1') 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 9: ordinal not in range(256)
```

The problem comes from the Right Single Quotation Mark. I do not manage to fix it.
Thanks for any advice.

Karim

Comment: THe character in the string in position 9 following  (Capture d) is malformed. If the file name is in your control; rename the file.

Comment: Thanks Akin. But I can not control the filename (uploaded file by any user). I thought I could replace the faulty character ...

Answer (score 0):

Since File name is not in your control, I would sanitize the file name.. 
Any of the methods in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021624/string-sanitizer-for-filename), would solve the problem.