# How do I replace or find non-printable characters in vim regex?

Tags: regex, vim, non-printable

I have a file with some non-printable characters that come up as ^C or ^B, I want to find and replace those characters, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: `/[^ -~]` Found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23103760/1663462

Comment: see here: https://superuser.com/a/1400632/510928

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Say you want to replace ^C with C:

`:%s/CtrlVC/C/g`

Where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> means type V then C while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> lets you enter control characters.

Comment: You can also use Ctrl-Q. This is useful for some users who map Ctrl-V to clipboard operations

Answer (score 93):

Removing control symbols only:

```
:%s/[[:cntrl:]]//g
```

Removing non-printable characters (note that in versions prior to ~8.1.1 this removes non-ASCII characters also):

```
:%s/[^[:print:]]//g
```

The difference between them could be seen if you have some non-printable-non-control characters, e.g. [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space):

[image]

Comment: At least until vim 7.3 [:print:] only matches ASCII printable characters (edited the answer to alert readers about this fact)

Comment: @ndemou This is tricky, with the [ ] around the [:print:] the ^ should invert the match and return any non-printable. Or perhaps that was your edit?

Comment: @dragon788, yes I was aware of how it works when I wrote my comment. Try the 2nd regex on text with printable Unicode characters outside the ASCII table to understand my comment (it will remove the Unicode characters).

Comment: @ndemou Have it changed in recent versions of Vim? I don't see any difference in the behavior of these two regexs in 8.1.1. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/NHS5EHr . Also, it doesn't remove non-ASCII characters, e.g. Chinese and Russian (the last part isn't something bad, just to point the difference).

Comment: @john-c-j I've just confirmed your observation. It was a bug anyway to consider printable Unicode characters as non printable. -- updated the answer (& waiting for peer review)

Comment: @ndemou But what is the difference between current behavior of these two regular expressions? When I tested them, they do exactly the same things, the result is shown in my screenshot posted above.

Comment: @john-c-j I can't think of a difference. However why do you think that there should be one? `[[:print:]]` and `[[:cntrl:]]` are by definition complementary so it's natural that `[^[:print:]] == [[:cntrl:]]` and `[^[:cntrl:]] == [[:print:]]` (remember that `[^[:xyz:]]` means any character except `[[:xyz:]]`) .

Comment: @ndemou "However why do you think that there should be one?" -- Well, because as stated in the answer, the first regex removes *control symbols*, whereas the second removes *non-printable characters*. As a corollary it could be said that there should be some difference between control symbols and  non-printable characters.

Comment: @john-c-j sure but I can't think of a non-printable character that is not a control character. I'm maybe too tired though :-)

Comment: @ndemou Well, I wondered for some example which will easily show the difference between them. And I found it :-) The difference between them could be seen if you have some non-printable-non-control characters, e.g. [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space): https://imgur.com/a/lqG0SlX. I edited the answer, currently awaiting for peer review.

Comment: @ndemou See here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18807 if you need to automate it without losing cursor position.

Comment: I like that this solution answers the problem stated in the question's title, not just the specific characters mentioned in the body of the question.

Answer (score 15):

Try this after saving your file in vim (assuming you are in Linux environment)

```
:%!tr -cd '[:print:]\n'
```

Comment: @JamesAndino: `:%` filters all lines using the external (`!`) programm `tr`, which _removes_ (`-d`) all characters that are _not_ (`-c`) _printable_ (`[:print:]`) or _newline_ (`\n`).

Comment: This isn't Unicode friendly, as it is a POSIX character class (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes). So if you have YAML with data like 你好, `tr` will strip the Unicode data when using `[:print:]`.

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers here using Vim's control characters worked for me.  I had to enter a unicode range.

```
:%s/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]//g
```

That unicode range was found on this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171868/231914

Comment: Because TAB is considered not-printable, So these [[:cntrl:]] and [^[:print:]] match TAB (0x9, C-I)

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
:%s/^C//g
```

To get the `^C` hold the control key, press `V` then `C` (Both while holding the control key) and the `^C` will appear. This will find all occurrences and replace them with nothing.

To remove both `^C` and `^B` you can do:

```
:%s/^C\|^B//g
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`CTRL-V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-V) prefix to enter them, or if they're not easily typeable, yank and insert them using [`CTRL-R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R) `"`.

Answer (score 5):

An option not mentioned in other answers.

Delete a specific unicode character with a long hex code, e.g. `<200b>`:

```
:%s/\%U200b//g
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for!  See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html