# Good and simple way to find invisible and unwanted characters

Tags: regex, vim, character, vim-plugin, invisible

As a learning developers on Debian, I encountered a really annoying problem: invisible character (different from EOL, space, indent etc). Literally PITA who makes you lose sometimes hours of debugging because you didn't thinked of them first. Now it's start to become a reflex but honnestly it's really hard to find them, specially where you are a rookie as me.

When you are sure what the line is the problem, you can just re-write it, simple but stupid. But now I have a blank page on my localhost and I can't find the line in my .php doing that.

When you do HTML/CSS you just have to display the source code from your browser. But for PHP as it's server side I don't think there is a dummy but simple solution like that.

Using vim, I tried to found something about it, and I can use :set list to find some character like this:

> set listchars=eol:¬,tab:>-,trail:·,extends:>,precedes:<

But it's not doing what I need, I saw some syntax to display some invisible characters, as this regex:

> \x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F

So, from that I can found some invisible characters, I still had to try it (how can I be sure there is invisible character to test it? How can I make some?). But is there an "official" or at least trustable and complete list of invisible characters? Debuging is annoying enough, I don't need to find the invisible man :-).

I tried to found something about vim, one of the most useful was probably this one: [Showing all invisible characters in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103466/showing-all-invisible-characters-in-vim)

Well, being French and just learning I have some characters like:

> éçà

Which are detected by:

> /[^ -~<09>] or /[^ -~]

Very annoying, as I comment a lot. And I can stop using these characters but it looks like a non-sense to me.

In this topic it's also said to try the latin1 encodage. Maybe it removes some possible invisible characters to be typed? Is it a good solution to find the encodage who fits me for programing? Able to use "éàç" and remove some of annoying char? It doesn't looks like a 100% perfect solution, just a part of it.

So, do you have an idea of a good way to hunt them and better, help me to don't type them accidentaly?

I really tried to find a perfect solution, but it seems to be so much way to do this and I'm a bit lost between that and my new programing knowledge.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of invisible characters are you typing accidentally? I have to say I've never had this problem.

Comment: @4castle On OSX `Command+Space` gives a non breaking space, that might be OPs problem.

Comment: A complete solution would be complicated, and would involve more exchanges back and forth than is allowed on SO.  `listchars` won't do, because it only covers a small set of characters.  Highlighting won't work either, because ranges of multi-byte characters don't work reliably.  As a crude solution you can try `:set termencoding=ascii`.  All non-ASCII characters will be shown as question marks.  Be careful __not__ to save your file after that.

Comment: @Katsura if I change the encoding for ascii I lose every special characters I need. So I won't go for that I think.

If I change the encoding for ascii (and code in qwerty maybe?), it'll avoid me to type invisible characters?