# How I can search in vim for non valid characters

Tags: vim

I've a file with has a invalid character, I want to learn how to search for those kind of characters. Please check image, is what appear after `..get Ale`

I've checked with an heximal editor and the value is

```
f480 8080 0d
```

[image: vim with weird character]

I tried with `/[^[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]` with it also returns spaces, dashes etc.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987362/how-to-get-vim-to-highlight-non-ascii-characters

Comment: You can search non-ascii `/[^\u0000-\u007F]`

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "invalid character," but if what you want is to search for non-printable characters, type:

```
/[^[:print:]]
```

If you want to search for ASCII hex `0d`, type: `/[\u000d]` or `/^Vx0d` where "^V" means [Ctrl]-V (type V while holding the "Control" key pressed).

Check this link for more info: [How do I replace or find non-printable characters in vim regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844311/how-do-i-replace-or-find-non-printable-characters-in-vim-regex)

Comment: I though this was going to work but not, this highlight spaces and ctrl characters but not the `?` question mark that appear in the image. this works: `/[^\u0000-\u007F]`