# UTF-8 problems PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I've always used ISO-8859-1 encoding, but I'm now going over to UTF-8.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

My MySQL DB is UTF-8, my PHP document is encoded in UTF-8, I set a UTF-8 charset, but it still doesn't work.

(it is special characters like æ/ø/å that doesn't work)

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: Are your meta tags set as UTF-8?

Comment: here are some goo utf-8 tips and solutions about encoding problems:
http://www.utf-8.de/index.php?area=tutorials

Comment: hmm what exactly doesn't work about those characters? what you paste above is valid utf8 http://hexutf8.com/?q=c3a62fc3b82fc3a5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure the connection to your database is also using this character set:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
```

According to the documentation of `mysql_set_charset` at php.net:

```
Note:
This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysql_query() to execute 
SET NAMES .. is not recommended.
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Check the character set of your current connection with:

```
echo mysql_client_encoding($conn);
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php

If you have done these things and add weird characters to your table, you will see it is displayed correct.

Comment: Note that as of PHP 5.5.0, `mysql_set_charset` is deprecated, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php.

For reference, the page states: **Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.**

Comment: mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); ([w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_set_charset.asp))

Answer (score 10):

Remember to set connection encoding to utf8 as well.

In ext\mysqli do
`$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`

In ext\mysql do
`mysql_set_charset("utf8")`

With other db extensions you might have to run query like
`SET NAMES 'utf8'`

[Some more details about connection encoding in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html)

As others point out, making sure your source code is utf-8 encoded also helps. Pay special attention to not having BOM (Byte Order Mark) - it would be sent to browser before any code is executed, so using headers or sessions would become impossible.

Answer (score 2):

After connecting to db, run query SET NAMES UTF8

```
$db = new db(...);
$db->query('set name utf8');
```

and add this tag to header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: this http-surrogate helps nothing. why not to send **original** HTTP header?

Answer (score 1):

Are you having this error? MySql SELECT UNION Illegal mix of collations Error? Just set you entire mysql to utf 8 then

```
SET character_set_connection = utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this after connecting to mysql:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

And encode PHP document in **UTF-8 without BOM**.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but now its resolved. Here is the solution:

1st: update ur table
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

2nd:
add this in the head section of the HTML code:

Regards
Saleha A.Latif

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays PDO is the recommended way to use mysql. With that you should use the connection string to set encoding. For example: "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"