# XML is not read correctly (ISO-8859-1 / UTF-8)

Tags: xml, utf-8, special-characters, iso-8859-1, affiliate

I have this little piece of code, reading a very easy affiliate XML.
The URL is http://pf.tradetracker.net/?aid=193104&encoding=iso-8859-1&type=xml-v2&fid=556821&r=tt-canvasholidays.nl&categoryType=2&additionalType=2

When I try to put this XML in an array and process it with some basic functions, it seems that special characters are being replaced by encoded ones.

For example the word `Château` in the original XML is replaced by `ChÃ¢teau` when I read the XML in my php as follows:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach($xml->product as $child) {
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($child->name);
  }
```

Had programmed an escape function that replaces most of the `Ãx`-things with the correct characters, but the "`Ã¢`" string seems to be not accepted in the php code.

I have read some articles about wrong database conversion, but I'm just reading and interpreting it from the source XML and in the `simplexml_load_file` is no encoding specified.

O btw, I'm not a very experienced php programmer, but just stuck to Wordpress in combination with proven technologies for affiliate productfeeds, until some French data was coming through :)

Hope you can help... Thanks in advance...

Comment: How are you checking the value of `$name`? Printing it out or writing to a file?

Comment: I print it by `echo($name."<br/>");`

Comment: Maybe this link can help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168955/special-characters-htmlentities-xml-php-iso-8859-1-and-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, your XML document is in iso-8859-1 encoding. But I suspect you're outputting `$name` to a UTF-8 encoded page (although it doesn't explain the conversion of `Château` to `ChÃ¢teau`).

Once you've resolved the character encoding issue, you shouldn't need to replace characters or try to fix them.

You can try one of the following (3 is best):

1. Set the output encoding to iso-8859-1
2. Convert the input XML to UTF-8 with `iconv`
3. Request the XML document in UTF-8: http://pf.tradetracker.net/?aid=193104&encoding=utf-8&type=xml-v2&fid=556821&r=tt-canvasholidays.nl&categoryType=2&additionalType=2

If you're still having problems, then I suspect your source document is being downloaded incorrectly.

The following code works fine for me (Using http://phphttpclient.com/downloads/httpful.phar):

```
<?php
include('./httpful.phar');

$xml_string = \Httpful\Request::get('http://pf.tradetracker.net/?aid=193104&encoding=utf-8&type=xml-v2&fid=556821&r=tt-canvasholidays.nl&categoryType=2&additionalType=2')->send();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

foreach($xml->product as $child) {
    echo $child->name . "<br>";
}
```

?>

**Update:**
It seems that SimpleXML will convert output to UTF-8 automatically, presumably based on the encoding declaration of the XML.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried utf-8 for the XML document too already, without any positive result. iconv didn't do anything to the result too...

Comment: Result of 3:
tt_Canvasholidays.nl
tt_Canvasholidays.nl_1_AR05S | Camping ChÃ¢teau de Boisson | 0.00 | Ardèche => succeeded
tt_Canvasholidays.nl_2_CE01X | Camping Val de Cantobre | 0.00 | Ardèche => succeeded

Comment: Result of 2 is the same. I added this code to my php:
iconv("iso-8859-1", "utf-8//TRANSLIT",$xml);
Even while step 3 was already implemented, so the original encoding of the XML-doc is utf-8.

Comment: Step 1 didn't influence the result either :(

Comment: Are you still running the result through your `mysql_real_escape_string()` function before printing the result?

Comment: Hi @rodney, I've updated my answer to include a working example. You shouldn't need `mysql_real_escape_string()` once everything is working.

Comment: I included your code as u specified, but still the output is "Camping ChÃ¢teau de Boisson"

Comment: Make sure your browser is running in "auto" encoding mode or UTF-8 mode. Through my testing I managed to knock my browser into iso-8859-1, which was breaking the response

Comment: Btw i "echo" it to have some sort of debug response. In the end, this data must be stored in a mysql database, but it is stored there like it is presented in the echo-output.

When i add the line
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
the output is presented right:
"Camping Château de Boisson"

Your line for the header seems to be critical to present the output right.

Comment: The two critical parts are: getting the content in UTF-8 format before passing to SimpleXML and ensuring the browser knows the correct encoding. 

Now that you've got good UTF-8 strings, ensure that your database is created as UTF-8 and your connection is set as UTF-8. Good luck :)

Comment: What do u think the encoding of the db column must be: utf8_bin or utf8_unicode_ci?

Comment: It's not my area of expertise. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526334/what-effects-does-using-a-binary-collation-have

Comment: Nice detail: just your header line for encoding did the work. When i removed all code tips, it is still presented right. Putting these strings into de database is still not working, with utf-8_bin or utf8_unicode_ci... :(

Comment: Your comments gave me some more understanding. Thanks for that. I will look into the other article.

Comment: Make sure your **connection** to your MySQL DB is also set to UTF-8. There's lots of SO questions on the subject and depends on which MySQL driver you're using. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4623748/1554386.
Again, make sure that you set the `Content-Type` header and the connection encoding in the page that reads data from the DB