# How to produce Euro symbol in C?

Tags: c, formatting, euro

Please give me a sample C program to produce the euro sysmbol. I'm using windows keyboard and program needs to be compiled in linux.

Update: Actually I need Euro symbol as a string and need to concatenate it with amount string.

I'm having Dell Latitude D620 laptop and tried using Alt+4, Alt+5, etc.. None of them prints the euro sysmbol.

Comment: Iirc on Unix-likes the character set and character encoding to use depends on the locale, so do `setlocale` first with an appropriate argument and then just output U+20AC in the correct encoding.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#C.2FC.2B.2B) might give you an idea on how to implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is entirely character encoding specific.

This question should sum up why there is no straight answer to your question:

[Hex representation of Euro Symbol €](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640354/hex-representation-of-euro-symbol)

Answer (score 2):

The Unicode standard code-point for the [Euro sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign) (€) is U+20AC.

If your system is running using [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as its native encoding, you can represent this glyph using the string `"\xE2\x82\xAC"`. The encoding uses three bytes to represent the 16-bit value of the code-point.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"\u20AC"`; this is UTF-8 encoding of Euro sign. More info [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm).

Comment: I think this is only the UCS code point of "€" and not the actual UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: C does not support \u in strings to embed Unicode code-points.